# Map caps-lock key to middle mouse click

Tags: xorg, keyboard, shortcut-keys, input-devices, xmodmap

Since I rarely use <kbd>caps-lock</kbd>, I'd like to map the key to a middle mouse click instead. I would also like to map <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to the original function of the caps lock key, should I ever need it.

I can map any keyboard shortcut to `xdotool click 2`, but the Gnome *Keyboard Shortcuts* dialog won't let me assign a command to the caps-lock key, even with modifiers.

I know this is a bit of a strange undertaking; How would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you first remove the lock modifier from the Caps Lock key you should then be able to assign the key in Keyboard Shortcuts, use the command below to do that:

```
echo  'remove lock = Caps_Lock' | xmodmap -
```

Comment: very good! any chance to get caps lock back onto alt+capslock?

Answer (score 3):

Another easy solution if you prefer to use a GUI is to install easystroke:

```
sudo apt-get install easystroke
```

You can easily map keyboard keys and shortcuts to mouse buttons as well as mouse gestures.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, new answer, copying myself from here:
https://superuser.com/questions/947807/emulate-left-mouse-button-with-capslock-key/1409757#1409757

I was looking for CapsLock = left click, which should be similar. After much experimentation I realized I got better results with `xdotool` instead of `xte`.

In my `~/.bashrc` (or whatever startup script is appropriate to your system) I added this line:

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap -e "keycode 66 ="
```

This removes the 'locking' behavior of Caps Lock and assigns that key (key 66) to nothingness. I was tinkering with putting this in other places like `.xinitrc`, but they never worked. It is fairly safe in `.bashrc` even though it does get re-run with every terminal session opened (depending on how your `.bashrc` is set up overall).

For `xbindkeys` I created the file ~/.xbindkeysrc with these lines:

```
"xdotool mousedown 1"
  c:66

"xdotool mouseup 1"
  release + c:66
```

A reboot or running `source ~/.bashrc` should make the `xmodmap` part work. To reload `xbindkeys`, try this:

```
killall xbindkeys
xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```