# How do I remap certain keys or devices?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm searching for a way to remap certain keys in ubuntu.

i.e.

I'd like to change <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>PgDown</kbd> to <kbd>End</kbd>.

Does a built-in command or a tool exist reassign keys in Ubuntu/GNOME?

Comment: checkout my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133113/emulate-keypad-on-laptop/142339#142339). It doesn't worth copy and paste same answer. Perhaps it would help you.

Comment: Any Emacs-like bindings here for CTRL-P/N for unit steps?

Comment: Since some time `xmodmap` is depricated! to get a system wide setting you have to use `xkb`. So edit the language file in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` to add your changes there.

See http://askubuntu.com/a/898462/34298

Comment: If you want to remap your keyboard keys or mouse buttons to certain keys, use "Input Remapper" by sezanzeb. It's VERY simple, it has a GUI, and it just WORKS. I just have set a certain shortcut to simulate a keyboard key, works well.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

**Notice:** As of 2013, Ubuntu and derivatives no longer use `xmodmap`, but instead use `xkb`. For more information see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04/347382#347382?newreg=4eb097870a15490ebbe39d78412f9797). The answer below is no longer relevant for current releases.

---

For remapping certain keys you need two tools. First [**xev**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xev.1.html) (command-line tool) and second [**xmodmap**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xmodmap.1.html) (also command-line tool). Both should be available in Ubuntu without extra installing them.

1. Start terminal window and run `xev`. Now it's active and waits for you to press a key. Then press the key whose behaviour you want to change. i.e. <kbd>PgUp</kbd>.
2. `xev` will output some information about the pressed key. The third line is important. It should look similar to:

   ```
    state 0x10, keycode 110 (keysym 0xff55, Prior), same_screen YES,
   ```

   in this example `Prior` is the name of the behaviour the key is assigned to at the moment, the number keycode is the internal id to recognize the key.
   Now do this with another key i.e. <kbd>PgDown</kbd> give this output

   ```
    state 0x10, keycode 115 (keysym 0xff56, Next), same_screen YES,
   ```

   Here again the interesting part for us is `keycode 115` and `Next` - the name of the behaviour.
3. now when you want to swap the two keys use `xmodmap`.

   ```
     xmodmap -e "keycode 110 = Next"
   ```

   This changes the key with keycode 110 on your keyboard to the action `Next`. It's pretty simple.

   Note that if the key you are mapping should have a different meaning when used with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (for example for British keyboard layouts, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> gives quotation marks) then you can simply list the secondary command after the first. For example if you want the key with code 53 to map to backslash normally, but to the bar symbol when used with shift, you might do:

   ```
     xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = backslash bar"
   ```

**Additional information:** The sequence of these mappings depends on the keyboard layout. It usually is <kbd>Key</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+Key</kbd>, <kbd>mode_switch+Key</kbd>, <kbd>mode_switch+Shift+Key</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr+Key</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr+Shift+Key</kbd>, but can be very different for more special layouts, like in case of the German *Neo 2* one. To skip a column use `NoSymbol`. Here is a [comprehensive list of all keysyms](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_keysyms).
You can see the concrete sequence for your layout by finding it in one of the files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.

**Note: These change are for the active X session only and will be lost after reboot.
When you want to save the changes permanently you have to run the following commands after the ones above:**

```
xmodmap -pke >~/.Xmodmap
```

(it creates a file named `.Xmodmap` in your home directory (`~`))

Then you have to create a file named **`.xinitrc`** in your home directory where you put command `xmodmap .Xmodmap` in.

You can now modify `.Xmodmap` and run `xmodmap .Xmodmap` from console to see the changes immediately. The changes in `.Xmodmap` will persist.

source: [Ubuntu Foruns](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7675138&postcount=2)

### Bonus stuff:

If the key you are remapping has different behavior depending on a state (
like how the keys in the numeric keyboard depend on NumLock) you simply have to do **`xmodmap -pm`** to get a list of modifiers and then do:

`xmodmap -e "KEYCODE MODIFIER = behaviour behaviour_with_modifier"`

Suppose, for example, that you want to get a period instead of a comma on the numeric keyboard (useful for most programmers), but you want to keep the "delete" behavior when NumLock is off.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 91 mod2 = KP_Delete period"
```

`mod2`, because `xmodmap -pm` tells us that `mod2` is `Num_Lock`, the other names are obtained by pressing the keys in `xev`.

Comment: `xev` is not able to catch `Fn` key pressings

Comment: The selected answer didn't work for remapping the Caps-lock key for me on Ubuntu 12.10.

I was able to to do this by going to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout Settings -> Options, which has a list of keys and alternative behaviors.  Worked flawlessly in Unity and terminal.

Comment: If you have multiple keyboards connected, will these tools see a difference between the same key on another keyboard?

Comment: @Jop I don't think so, since what you are changing is the response to the keycode and the keycodes of the to keyboards should overlap.

Comment: Strange, I did everything, but my keymappings still reset after restarting.

Comment: I don't think I have an `-event` flag in Ubuntu 12.04. It throws an error and doesn't mention "event" in `man xev`.

Comment: fwiw: after logging the results of `xev` to a file called `event.out` I filter the non-keypress events with `perl -e '$/ = "\n\n"; while(<>) { print $_ if $_ =~ "KeyPress"; }' event.out > keypress.event.out`.

Comment: `xmodmap -e "KEYCODE MODIFIER = behaviour behaviour_with_modifier"` ... Where did you get this from? It doesn't seem to work, and I can't find any other reference / docs on this syntax ...

Comment: This answer is still relevant for Ubuntu 14.04 and works just fine, you just have to run the commands each time you login.

Comment: 1. If .xinitrc does not work, try .xsessionrc instead; 
2. Avoid setxkbmap overwriting xmodmap: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451945

Comment: ubuntu server 18.04, without LightDM/GDM and Desktop Environment, simply `startx` and `xmodmap -e` in `.xinitrc`: `xmodmap` works.

Comment: I am able to disable Function keys like F1 using the command xmodmap -e 'keycode 67=' . But need to disable a combination like "Control Alt F1", how to do that ?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: `Fn` is a special hardware key that is meant to be handled by low-level software like firmware, and work even if there is no operating system running at all or it isn’t even officially on. Remapping it can be done, but it required changing said firmware. Which hopefully will be open source if the owner was wise. :)

Comment: @Subhajit: If keycode 67 isn’t mapped to F1 anymore, there is no way to cause a Control-Alt-F1 keypress anymore either, nor any oney combo with F1 in it, as there is no F1 key to press, unless there is another keyboard or another keycode is mapped to F1.

Comment: If you want to remap your keyboard keys or mouse buttons to certain keys, use "Input Remapper" by sezanzeb. It's VERY simple, it has a GUI, and it just WORKS. I just have set a certain shortcut to simulate a keyboard key, works well.

Answer (score 27):

If you're trying to move a Shift key, there are a few extra steps:

```
 xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Up" # Shift => Up
 xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Shift_R" # Up => Shift
 xmodmap -e "add shift = Shift_R" # Make the new Shift key actually do shifting
 xmodmap -e "remove shift = Up" # Prevent the old Shift key from shifting
 xset r 62 # Make the new Up key autorepeat
 xset -r 111 # Prevent the new Shift key from autorepeating
```

Comment: +1 The most unix-y answer of all of those for a modifier (I had already done so way, way back with my iBook 2, when I wanted the enter key to have the function of Control_R, but had forgotten the details).

Comment: An important answer for users using keyboards on Lenovo Laptops

Comment: Since xmodmap is specifically programed to allow modifier key swappings, according to the man page, this should be doable atomically.

Answer (score 16):

I've just had an afterthought.. I think you may mean something entirely different by "remap".. but I'll leave my answer as it is...  (I don't know how to re-assign one key to behave as another)

**UPDATE**: my 'afterthought' has been confirmed; ( I've answered the wrong question :)... please see NES's Community Wiki answer (accepted above).

There are two general ways to <strike>remap</strike> rebind a key.

- locally to a particular program
  (a key can be used for different things in different apps/windows)
- globally for a specific user
  (a key has the same function in all windows)

For 'local to a program' methods, there is sometimes a way to change keybindings offered by the app itself... eg.

`Firefox` has an addon called [keyconfig](http://mozilla.dorando.at/) ... for some info see this [MozillZine post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)

Most Ubuntu programs are Gnome based and there is a specific utility to modify the keybinding for any menu item of these Gnome apps... It is called `Editable Menu Accelerator` ... It is a very 'touchy' tool, but quite powerful.. You can enable it by running `gconf-editor` (via Terminal or Alt+F2)... navigate to `desktop`--`gnome`--`interface` and select `can_change_accels` .... You can then change menu items to virtual anything you like (per program/window)... I suggest you disable it as soon as you've done what you need..

Otherwise you can set up Global hotkeys.  I use a program called [xbindkeys](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xbindkeys) [image: Install xbindkeys], and there is also an option available via the Main Menu -- Preferences, called `Keyboard Shortcuts`

If you use xbindkeys, you will need to add it to your "Startup Applications" (Main Menu -- Preferences) ... Also (as suggested by Stefano Palazzo) I have previously written a more detailed description of xbindkeys in an answer on this [askubuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15050/how-do-i-bind-sh-files-to-keyboard-combination)

Comment: +1, very nice! A suggestion: You should integrate your [great answer from another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15050/how-do-i-bind-sh-files-to-keyboard-combination) into this one, maybe also explain the configuration format of xbindkeys a little bit.

Comment: The bit about assigning other keys could be handled by `xdotool`, check out the man page, I've used it to solve [this problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17294/map-caps-lock-key-to-middle-mouse-click).

Comment: i recently found another approach with a tool called xmodmap in combination with a tool called xev. i don't know what the differences between xmodmap and xbindkeys are, but this works pretty well for me. some advice with tool to prefer of the named two? Here is a very helpful step by step guide which describes xmodmap and xev http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7675138&postcount=2

Comment: @NES.. It appears I've addressed the wrong point.. You seem to want to actually remap the way a particular key is interpreted by the OS, ie, a non-standard keyboard interpretation, whereas I've been refering to a standard keyboard-interpretation, and simply overloading the default key-assignments.  (I think what you are after is similar to swapping the left and right mouse buttons) .. Well it seems my answer was good for the wrong thing :)

Comment: yes, but no problem. the answer is also interesting. the step by step guide i posted the link above was the right way. so i'll post a short answer with the solution that other users have a good guide. thanks fred

Comment: The Keyboard > Shortcuts tip worked perfectly for me. My need was fairly simple, though; I just wanted to open the file manager, and there's a Home Folder setting under Launchers.

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I tried to switch the mapping of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key
(and vice versa):

```
$ uname -a
```

REPORTS:

```
Linux box 2.6.32-37-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 20:35:14 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

$ which xmodmap
```

REPORTS:

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap

$ which xev
```

REPORTS:

```
/usr/bin/xev

$ xev
```

(ignore the next fifty lines or so)

```
PRESS THE ENTER KEY (notice the third line):
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x110, subw 0x0, time 263441120, (738,242), root:(771,314),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d)
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d)
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x110, subw 0x0, time 263441271, (738,242), root:(771,314),
    state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (0d)
    XFilterEvent returns: False

PRESS THE SHIFT KEY (notice the third line):
KeyPress event, serial 30, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x110, subw 0x0, time 263592202, (464,368), root:(497,440),
    state 0x0, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x5600001,
    root 0x110, subw 0x0, time 263592298, (464,368), root:(497,440),
    state 0x1, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What's important is the third line of each keypress:

```
FOR:
state 0x0, keycode 36 (keysym 0xff0d, Return), same_screen YES,
The name "Return" is the name of the behavior of the key pressed.
The number of the key pressed is "36".

state 0x0, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
The name "Shift_R" is the name of the behavior of the key pressed.
The number of the key pressed is "62".
```

REVERSE THE MAPPING:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Return"
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 36 = Shift_R"
```

SAVE THE RESULTS:

```
$ xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
$ vi ~/.xinitrc
```

ADD

```
 xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap

$ sudo reboot
```

The main problem was that the reversal did NOT work.
The <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key was mapped to the <kbd>SHIFT_R</kbd> key; but the <kbd>SHIFT_R</kbd> key was not mapped to the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. Go figure.

Answer (score 8):

In order to do global remaps independently of X, you can make use of **console-setup(5)** instead.

In my case I wanted to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>D</kbd>, since my <kbd>D</kbd>-key is broken :)

First I used **dumpkeys(1)** to get a template for a mapping, in the case of the <kbd>D</kbd>-key, the interesting bit is the mapping for keycode 32 (on my keyboard); **Note that there are two spaces in the grep pattern!**

```
$ sudo dumpkeys | grep "keycode  32" > tempfile
$ cat tempfile
keycode  32 = +d
    shift   keycode  32 = +D
    altgr   keycode  32 = +eth
    shift   altgr   keycode  32 = +ETH
    control keycode  32 = Control_d
    shift   control keycode  32 = Control_d
    altgr   control keycode  32 = Control_d
    shift   altgr   control keycode  32 = Control_d
(121 lines total...)
```

In order to change the map to apply to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> (keycode 58 on my keyboard) instead

```
sed 's/32/58/' -i tempfile
```

Now it reads

```
keycode  58 = +d
    shift   keycode  58 = +D
    altgr   keycode  58 = +eth
(etc...)
```

To add this remap to the default map, it simply needs to be appended to the remap include file for **console-setup**

```
sudo sh -c 'cat tempfile >> /etc/console-setup/remap.inc'
```

and **console-setup** needs to be reconfigured (skipping low priority questions with `-phigh`)

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup -phigh
```

Now the remap should be completed, and be loaded automatically on boot.

Answer (score 3):

I spent one whole day in trying to create a shortcut for `Ctrl+Pageup`.

I first tried `xmodmap` but that can't generate modifier events. So it is impossible to create a shortcut that generates for example the `Control` event.

I then tried `xbindkeys` with `xmacro`. That sort of works, but `xbindkeys` is not able to capture some key combinations on my system, such as `Alt + ___`.

So I finally used Unity's own Keyboard Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts to setup my shortcut.

And instead of `xmacro`, I have now used `xvkbd` program to generate the keyboard events, but that is just a personal preference. Both `xmacro` and `xvkbd` work almost the same. One additional tip is to add a delay parameter in `xmacro` or `xvkbd` to ensure that the events don't get lost.

Answer (score 3):

For me AutoKey from Software Center worked the best. It has intuitive GUI, to add new binding click New -> Phrase and

1. Add name, click OK
2. At "Phrase Settings" section make sure the paste using is set to keyboard
3. Add hotkey that you want to use
4. Add command into text field, eg to emulate left arrow key - it'd be `<left>` (list of special keys is [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Special-Keys)).

Comment: This worked perfekt to set up `Super+C` and `Super+V` to `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V`
. Just the perfect solution when using Ubuntu via VirtualBox on a mac

Comment: However, this does not disable other commands that listen to these shortcuts. To disable `Super+V` to "show the notification list" go to Setting -> Devices -> Keyboard and disable it there

Comment: @Ben yup, it would be great if it displayed bindings of other apps, but it's rather icing on the cake. My problem is that it's not possible to remap "Fn" key. I've decided to try out uhk keyboard - that thing programmable independent of os, will see how it goes.

Comment: @BeKind Have you succeed with uhk keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

You could also try https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper

It runs in the background and actively injects mapped keycodes.

---

While this adds some extra flexibility, if all you need is remap a single button and be done you could try to use xmodmap. Looks like that has already be explained in detail.

Or write an xkb "symbols" file and use setxkbmap, but I wouldn't recommend that. setxkbmap can be used on a per-device basis as well.

Writing xkb or xmodmap configurations caused trouble for me though if both devices report the same keycode, even though the configuration maps them to different characters, when pressing them simultaneously (which is the main reason why I had to write the injection tool for that)

And recently I came across this solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/k3h9qv/remapping_keys_using_hwdb_files/

Comment: Couldn't resist to create an extra comment to tell how great key-mapper is! Remapping shortcuts is now a joy! Huge thanks! It definitely should be more popular.

Comment: Forgot to add that it even works with Wayland!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remap a key for a specific program only, I've [just added](https://github.com/CyberShadow/hax11/commit/ba694c6619d90dbc54823368526dcc9e19d5ccbb) this feature to hax11.

> I'd like to change <kbd>PgUp</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>PgDown</kbd> to <kbd>End</kbd>.

To do this with hax11, open the program's profile configuration file under `~/.config/hax11/profiles` (e.g. `~/.config/hax11/profiles/usr\lib\firefox\firefox`), and add:

```
Enable=1
MapK112=K110
MapK117=K115
```

Answer (score 1):

### Non-Persistant remap via .desktop shortcut

*In my case I wanted to remap the keypad decimal point to a comma, but only temporarily, so* `xmodmap` *satisfies this requirement in my case*

- Find out what is the **keycode** for the specific key to remap and the **keysym** I want to map too.

  - `:~$ xev | grep keycode`
- Press the keys of interest and monitor the stdout

```
    state 0x10, keycode 91 (keysym 0xffae, KP_Decimal), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 129
    state 0x10, keycode 59 (keysym 0x2c, comma), same_screen YES,
```

- 1st I pressed the key I want to remap and 2nd I pressed the key I want to map to.

  - Keycode of key I want to remap : `..., keycode 91 (...`
  - Keysym I want that keycode to map to: `...(keysym 0x2c, comma),...`
- Find out what the current mapping for the keycode to remap is:

  - `:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep "keycode\s*91"`

```
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
```

As specified in the manpage of xmodmap: *Up to eight keysyms may  be attached to a key..* : **1st** keysym is used when **no** modifier key, **2nd** with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, etc... *This does not correspond exactly to what was happening in my case but trial and error allowed me to discover the the 2nd positional argument was the one I was after*

- Map to the new config.

  - `:~$ xmodmap -e "keycode 91 = KP_Delete comma KP_Delete KP_Decimal"`
- Map back to original config.

  - `:~$ xmodmap -e "keycode 91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal"`
- I created a couple `.desktop` shortcuts in `~\.local\share\applications\` to easily switch to one or the other configuration:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=KeyPad comma
Exec=xmodmap -e "keycode 91 = KP_Delete comma KP_Delete KP_Decimal"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/home/paui/.icons/KP_comma.png
```

**Extra info:**
***state field*** output of `xev`,

The state field is the "sum" of current active modifiers. These are the ones I deciphered.

```
    0x01 Shift
    0x02 Caps
    0x04 Control
    0x08 Alt
    0x10 NumLock
    0x80 Alt Gr
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using XKB predefined configuration Options

**If your lucky**, perhaps the specific remap you want to perform is already integrated into a set of predefined options you can add to a your current configuration with [setxkbmap](http://manpagez.com/man/1/setxkbmap/).

1. on a Terminal open the [manpage of xkeyboard-config](http://manpagez.com/man/7/xkeyboard-config/) `:~$ man xkeyboard-config`
2. Scroll down or search with `\` for your specific configuration option. *in my case I wanted to remap the keypad Delete key to a comma instead of a period, and I was in luck*

```
 ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │Option               Description                                 │
 ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
 │kpdl:dot             Legacy key with dot                         │
 │kpdl:comma           Legacy key with comma                       │
 │kpdl:dotoss          Four-level key with dot                     │
 │kpdl:dotoss_latin9   Four-level key with dot, Latin-9 only       │
 │kpdl:commaoss        Four-level key with comma                   │
 │kpdl:momayyezoss     Four-level key with momayyez                │
 │kpdl:kposs           Four-level key with abstract separators     │
 │kpdl:semi            Semicolon on third level                    │
 │                                                                 │
 └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

3. check your current keyboard configuration with `:~$ setxkbmap -query`

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     es,gb
variant:    winkeys,
```

4. add the option to the current configuration: `:~$ setxkbmap -option kpdl:commaoss`

```
:~$ setxkbmap -query
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     es,gb
variant:    winkeys,
options:    kpdl:commaoss
```

5. To remove all options, use an empty option argument `:~$ setxkbmap -option`

If you require a mapping that is not predefined there, such as the example you placed, you will need to have to write it yourself [as explained in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65600/43437)