# ThinkPad workaround for no "super" key

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, thinkpad

My ThinkPad x43 has no <kbd>Super</kbd> key. Most of the keyboard shortcuts in 11.04 use this button:
[What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/unity-keyboard-mouse-shortcuts)

What to do with Unity now? Is there a way to map the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button to super or something like this?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't mind losing your left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, you can swap it with the <kbd>Win</kbd> key.

Open the `Keyboard` control panel, go to the `Layout` tab and select `Options...`.  Expand the `Alt/Win key behaviour` section, and select `Left Alt is swapped with Left Win`.

Answer (score 3):

You can remap almost anything to <kbd>Super</kbd>. Assuming the below is really an x43 keyboard (the internet swears it is), I'd go for the page left/page right keys on either side of the up-arrow on the bottom right. You're likely to regret remapping <kbd>Fn</kbd>.  [image]

You probably need to use `xev` and `xmodmap`. This is a command line operation.

See also: [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) -- be sure to read past the accepted answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, xev doesn't register fn or fn key combinations. FWIW, I wouldn't mind keeping the fn use for brightness, but making it, when pressed alone or with another key, otherwise act like Super.

Answer (score 3):

Using the keyboard layout properties I set <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> as another <kbd>Super</kbd> key and then it works the same way as a <kbd>Windows</kbd> key it seems. At least it opens the Dash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=530346) that covers this.

You can also check out [ThinkWiki](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkWiki), which specialises in setting up Linux on ThinkPads and see it they've come up with a solution, if the other one doesn't work.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I know, but at that particular time, I didn't have time to do much research, so I was just trying to point him in the right direction.