# xmodmap modifications aren't enough - anything else I can do?

Tags: 10.04, keyboard-layout

I'm using an Apple keyboard which has some annoyances compared to other keyboards. Namely, the Alt_L and Super_L keys are swapped, and the bar and less keys are swapped ("|" and "<").

I've written an Xmodmap file to swap the keys back:

```
keycode  49 = less greater less greater onehalf threequarters
keycode  64 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode  94 = bar section bar section brokenbar paragraph
keycode 108 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 133 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 134 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
```

I did this by identifying the keys using `xev` and the default modmap `xmodmap -pke` and swapping the keycodes. `xev` now identifies all my keys as correct, which is awesome! I can also use the correct keys to type the bar and less than symbols. (I followed this answer on askubuntu: [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24916/52719))

But it seems the change isn't very deep. Here are some examples

- The Super key is now broken in the Compiz Settings Manager. No shortcuts involving the Super key works (but the Alt key does).
- The settings dialog for **Gnome Do** doesn't heed the changes in xmodmap, and I can't open the **Gnome Do** window anymore if I use any of the remapped keys.
- Chrome shortcuts doesn't care about the xmodman changes, I now have to use Super+D to focus the address field (Should be Alt+D)

So to summarize, everything broke.

I would like a deeper way of telling Ubuntu (or any other Linux distro for that matter) which keys are which on the keyboard. Is there a way to edit the Keyboard Layout directly? I'm using the Norwegian Bokmål keyboard layout. Does it reside in a file somewhere I could edit?

Any comments, previous experiences or relevant stray thoughts would be greatly appreciated -

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I finally got this working after hours of trying. I found the file where the evdev scancodes are translated into xfree86 keycodes under X11, namely `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`. I opened that file as root and moved the key codes around using the default xmodmap settings as a reference (`xmodmap -pke`). My final edits were quite simple:

```
<LSGT> = 49; // This was 94
<TLDE> = 94; // This was 49
<LWIN> = 64; // This was 133
<LALT> = 133; // This was 64
<RWIN> = 108; // This was 134
<RALT> = 134; // This was 108
```