# Emulate Keypad on Laptop

Tags: shortcut-keys, numpad

I have a laptop without a numeric keypad on which I'm running Ubuntu 12.04, and I very much enjoy playing roguelike games. Such games tend to require a numpad for movement, targeting, &c., as one is able to operate in the eight cardinal directions. To get around the limitation of not having a numpad, I would like to be able to bind a key combination, for example <kbd>Shift + Left Arrow</kbd> to another key, in this case <kbd>1</kbd>; unfortunately, my research so far has only turned up how to bind a key combination to a command. I'm sure there's something blaringly obvious that I'm missing, but as for what it is ...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are playing at home, you can just plug a normal keyboard to your laptop. I bet that's the easiest way, no fuss with software, Plug-n-Play!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you want to do that on Windows there is very useful scripting language [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which can do a lot with scripting interface.

A perfect alternative to [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). Very useful whether you want to remap keys or assign abbreviation(*adr*) and it will write your full address!!

> AutoKey is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows
>   you to manage a collection of scripts and phrases, and assign
>   abbreviations and hotkeys to these. This allows you to execute a
>   script or insert text on demand in whatever program you are using.

#### Latest version is v0.90.

- Where to get this? It is in the ubuntu's repository!

Open software center > search for `autokey` > install AutoKey(GTK)

- How to use this?

Open AutoKey.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or from File>Create..>New Phrase. Rename with whatever you like. 
[image]
[image]

Enter keys In right panel(remove text `Enter phrase contents`) you want to *get typed* (in your case <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> so will type `<shift>+<left>` )when you hit some key. full info for *Special Keys* like shift,arrow, etc. are described [here](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Special-Keys). 
[image]

Then in bottom-right corner there is three `Set` buttons to set for `Abbreviation` or `Hotkey` or `Window Filter` or all of them.

Click `Set` for `Hotkey`. You will be prompted to give HotKeys. If you want to make it run with single key (in your case <kbd>1</kbd>) Don't click on any other button than `Press to Set`.
[image]

Click `Press to Set` and hit a key you want to assign(in your case <kbd>1</kbd>).

Click `OK`.

Click `Save` in bottom-right corner.
[image]
 Now try by hitting <kbd>1</kbd> wherever you want.

You need to keep AutoKey running, or you can add in startup list for command `autokey-gtk`

[Amazing tutorial is here](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/autokey-linux-utility-for-text-substitution-hotkeys-and-desktop-automation/) :))

here is some [Sample Scripts](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Scripting#basic-scripts) If you'd like to do something more.

Comment: Does this still work? ppa:cdekter/ppa hasn't been updated since 2012.

Comment: No longer seems to work in Ubuntu 17.10 -- may be a gnome/wayland thing

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty much answered in other questions [like this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys), but the short version is you should be able to do this level of remapping with xmodmap. I have done this sort of thing for mapping key combinations to the multimedia key actions, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank your share, I mapping the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> to be <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, now I like my HHKB better.

If you have HHKB, you can also setting under:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> = <kbd>~</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> =  <kbd>Home</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> =  <kbd>End</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> =  <kbd>PgUp</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> =  <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

by the way, I note it at my blog ---- [凍仁的筆記：HHKB Pro 2](http://note.drx.tw/2013/03/hhkb-pro2.html).