# How to change the functionality of keyboard special keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard

Different keyboards come with different special keys. For example mine has a key for bringing up the calculator, another for putting the to sleep, another for opening email client and so on...

My question is, how can I change what these keys do? For instance I want my email key (since I never use it) perform as the `Next` key on my music player?

Comment: Have you tried keyboard shortcuts under system settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your special case go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → `Shortcuts` → `Sound and Media`. Click onto "Next track ... Audio next" and press your <kbd>✉</kbd> email key:

[image: edit shortcuts]

This is the right place for connecting keys or key combinations with actions; it is possible to set up custom commands, too.

If you wish to configure several keys on your keyboard, go to **System Settings** and check out **Keyboard Layout** → `Options`. There you can edit the Caps Lock <kbd>⇪</kbd> behaviour, for example:

[image: keyboard layout]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this manually through configuration files, or you can use [KeyTouch](http://keytouch.sourceforge.net/), which has profiles for different keyboard models and allows you to change the functions of special keys on those models. It was in the software centre last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

you can change behavior of any key using `AutoKey`.

more info and guide can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141479/dell-inspiron-n5110-keyboard-touchpad/144207#144207) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133113/emulate-keypad-on-laptop/142339#142339) in my answer.