# how to use "WIN+NUM" as a HOTKEY?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I'm using 12.04, `WIN+1` is a hotkey in Unity, and now I've removed unity and changed shell to `gnome-shell-3.4`, but I still cannot use `WIN+NUM` as an hotkey `change to desktop NUM`, I set it in system settings but nothing happens.

thks for any help.

Comment: Check my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/133113/emulate-keypad-on-laptop/142339#142339

Comment: and this http://askubuntu.com/questions/141479/dell-inspiron-n5110-keyboard-touchpad/144207#144207

Comment: @virpara post it here too! :)

Comment: @virpara for navigation-change to desktop 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume that you want to bind for any bash command.*

### 1.0 First get commands to change workspace from terminal

- Go to first workspace. Open terminal and run `wmctrl -d | awk '{print $6}` for me it yields `0,0` note it as co-ordinates of first workspace.
- Move terminal to Next workspace and do above procedure again for all workspaces.

My output after doing above steps

```
virpara@Ascension:~$ wmctrl -d | awk '{print $6}' #in workspace 1
0,0
virpara@Ascension:~$ wmctrl -d | awk '{print $6}' #in workspace 2
1366,0
virpara@Ascension:~$ wmctrl -d | awk '{print $6}' #in workspace 3
0,768
virpara@Ascension:~$ wmctrl -d | awk '{print $6}' #in workspace 4
1366,768
```

You may be thinking **What we've got after doing this?** we have co-ordinates to switch to desired workspace.

We can use `wmctrl -o X,Y` to switch to respective workspaces. where `X,Y` are your workspace co-ordinates.

For me, Commands to switch to workspaces are as follows,

```
For Workspace 1 => wmctrl -o 0,0
For Workspace 2 => wmctrl -o 1366,0
For Workspace 3 => wmctrl -o 0,768
For Workspace 4 => wmctrl -o 1366,768
```

### 2.0 Set HotKeys for those commands

#### How to install AutoKey

Open software center > search for autokey > install AutoKey(GTK)

#### How to bind any key ?

#### Step 1 :

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or from `File > Create.. > New Script`. Rename with whatever you like.

[image]

#### Step 2 :

Paste below code as shown, I'll bind <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to Workspace 1. Replace `wmctrl -o 0,0` with your command.

```
import os
os.system("wmctrl -o 0,0")
```

[image]

#### Step 3 :

Then in bottom-right corner there is three `Set` buttons to set for `Abbreviation` or `Hotkey` or `Window Filter`. Click second `Set` button (because we want to set hotkey).

[image]

#### Step 4 :

Click `Super` then Click `Press to Set` and hit a key you want to assign(in your case <kbd>1</kbd>. I'm hitting <kbd>1</kbd>).

[image]

#### Step 5 :

Click `OK`.

#### Step 6 :

Click `Save` in bottom-right corner.

[image]

Try hitting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

Go to `Step 1 :` and do this for all commands you got earlier in `1.0` to bind to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd> .

Comment: well, but what if I want to use WIN+1,2,3 to change to desktop 1,2,3...?

Comment: @namiheike I've edited answer.

Comment: thks, it works.

Comment: well, but if I press WIN+2 in a textbox, It will first input a '2' char, then change to desk 2, is there any way to solve this? sendkey another backspace?

Comment: are you sure you have set _Hotkey_ ? It doesn't happen with me.

Comment: well, I should check the option "trigger immediately". thx

Comment: **Tip:** using the script as shown above, `os.system("gedit")`, Autokey can become a true launcher! As long as the shortcuts do not interfere with 12.04 Unity's new keystrokes, all will be well.