# Request for a guide on setting up Apple Aluminium keyboard on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, xkb, print-screen

Is there a working solution to set up Apple Aluminium keyboard on Ubuntu with F13-F15 remapped to Print Screen, Scroll Lock and Pause?

[image: Apple Aluminum Keyboard]

So far, I came up with the following solution:

1. In /etc/default/keyboard, set `XKBMODEL="applealu_ansi"`.
2. Make sure `apple:alupckeys` is in xkb-options (e.g. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:ralt_switch', 'grp:ctrl_shift_toggle', 'misc:typo', 'apple:alupckeys']"`). Setting `XKBOPTIONS` in /etc/default/keyboard doesn't seem to have any effect since the settings in Gnome have higher prioriry.
3. Reboot.

With the steps above, Keyboard Layout Chart shows the following picture:

[image: eKeyboard Mapping]

All three Print Screen, Scroll Lock and Pause are recognized correctly. They are highlighted on the chart when corresponding keys are pressed on the keyboard. But the problem is that neither Print Screen, nor Pause (I use it as a replacement for Ctrl+Alt+L to lock screen) *don't work*. Sometimes cursor disappears when Print Screen is pressed, but the actual screenshot is not taken.

Another problem is that with *applealu_ansi* set as the keyboard model, the Alt+Tab combination starts closing windows while switching through them. Is it a bug or feature?

I've been observing the above behavior on two different computers with Ubuntu 16.04, so it doesn't seem a misconfiguration issue.

Any ideas on how to set it up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

see

http://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys

http://askubuntu.com/questions/133113/emulate-keypad-on-laptop/142339#142339

http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_keysyms

```
terminal > xev > press key > view keycode xxx
```

then remap

```
xmodmap -e "keycode xxx = [event]"
```

[event]=Print, Scroll_Lock, Pause