# Remap arrow keys to a new key combination

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, xkb

The Left, Up and Down keys on my keyboard are broken and won't register any key codes. I have tested it using xev.

I would like to make the following keys trigger the key codes associated with the broken keys.

```
<Win> h -> Left
<Win> j -> Down
<Win> k -> Up
<Win> l -> Right
```

I have read that this is a job for xkb, but I don't know how to go about it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/482678/how-to-add-a-new-keyboard-layout-custom-keyboard-layout-definition,

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82837/how-do-i-make-the-caps-lock-key-a-third-shift-key

Comment: Likely helpful:  http://askubuntu.com/a/483026/225694

Answer (score 3):

Apparently I need 50 reputation to comment.

I have found a similar post here:
[Emulate Keypad on Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133113/emulate-keypad-on-laptop/142339#142339)

Also here:
[How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Comment: The last link is dead.

Comment: Link has been updated