# Make a keyboard key act as another

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My period key recently broke and I've been trying to figure out how to make another key act as it so that I can continue using my keyboard. I never use my right shift or right alt so if there is a way to make either of those replace my period key, that would be great. Any ideas?

I use the latest release of Xubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04 xenial).

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in either of these posts? [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) or  [Emulate Keypad on Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133113/emulate-keypad-on-laptop/142339#142339)