# How to change decimal comma to decimal period in numpad?

Tags: command-line, xmodmap, awesome

How to change the decimal comma ',' to decimal period '.' in the numeric pad of the keyboard?

I have used `xmodmap` but every time that I change my keyboard layout the changes (by xmodmap) are being reset.

Comment: Have you seen this answer ? [How do I remap certain keys?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys/24930#24930)

Comment: I imagine that this would be part of the keyboard layout, no? If it is a US-style keyboard you may be able to switch to a European-style where that key would likely be a comma. You'll have to suffer the consequences of having a Pound (curreny) sign instead of a pound (hash) on the Shift-3 however.

Comment: @NikTh I have seen this answer, however when I change the keyboard layout the changes are vanished (as mentioned in my question).

Comment: How are you saving the settings? Putting them in `~/.Xmodmap` and then putting `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in `~/.xinitrc` usually works. Alternatively, you could add the command `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` as a startup item.

Comment: @Mik - The `Xmodmap` are being called by a startup script, which is working until changing keyboard layout where Xmodmap settings are being reset.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are mixing `xmodmap` commands with `setxkbmap` commands (whether on the command-line or by using the graphical settings menus). As you have observed, the `setxkbmap` commands will override the `xmodmap` commands when you change your keyboard layout. The logical solution would therefore be to use `setxkbmap` to change both your layout *and* the keypad comma to a decimal period.

When you use `setxkbmap` to change your layout any specified customisations will also be applied: the full list of options is available at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst`. I don't know which language layouts you use, so I have placed just two examples at the end of the following command, which you can use to switch layouts with <kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. If you have any more key mappings or bindings you want to activate, simply add them to the command:

```
setxkbmap -option '' -option kpdl:dot -option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle gb,nl
```

The first command switch (`-option ''`) clears any current settings, as when new settings are given they are added to and do not replace any existing ones unless this option is used. The second (`-option kpdl:dot`) makes sure that the appropriate keypad key is a dot or period; the third command switch (`-option grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle`) sets up your ability to switch the layouts with <kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, and the last (`gb,nl`) specifies the layouts to switch to.

To check your settings, you can enter

```
setxkbmap -query
```

which results in:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     gb,nl
options:    kpdl:dot,grp:switch,grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Add the full `setxkbmap` line further above as a startup item to make sure it is activated and available for you to use.

More information on `setxkbmap` is available by entering `man setxkbmap` or by viewing the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/setxkbmap.1.html).

Comment: I have the same problem again. However in Ubuntu 14.04 I switch layouts with `Super` + `Space`. What kind of command must I use in this case?

Answer (score 18):

In Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, there are at least two ways to do this.
Assumptions:

1. You want to do this for Unity (graphical environment).
2. The goal is just to change comma to dot, not to change the whole layout or other options.

---

### Option 1: GUI (dconf-editor)

Run (Alt+F2) "dconf-editor", navigate in the tree to schema "org.gnome.desktop.input-sources" and set the key "xkb-options" to value that you want, e.g. "['kpdl:comma']" or "['kpdl:dot']".

Values are defined in xkeyboard-config help:

```
man xkeyboard-config
```

This is what I found there:

```
Numeric keypad delete key behaviour
   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │Option               Description                                 │
   ├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
   │kpdl:dot             Legacy key with dot                         │
   │kpdl:comma           Legacy key with comma                       │
   │kpdl:dotoss          Four-level key with dot                     │
   │kpdl:dotoss_latin9   Four-level key with dot, Latin-9 only       │
   │kpdl:commaoss        Four-level key with comma                   │
   │kpdl:momayyezoss     Four-level key with momayyez                │
   │kpdl:kposs           Four-level key with abstract separators     │
   │kpdl:semi            Semicolon on third level                    │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

---

### Option 2: Command line (gsettings)

You can also use command line instead of dconf-editor GUI to accomplish the same. Like this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['kpdl:comma']"
```

Comment: I don't have any program called "dconf-editor".

Comment: I am not sure if it is installed by default. It depends on what distribution you have. It should be part of Gnome-based Ubuntu distributions (i.e. not Kubuntu for example). https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/dconf

Comment: If you want to install it, simply run "sudo apt-get install dconf-editor".

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. Worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04 beta (after `sudo apt install dconf-editor`). Thank you!