# Change decimal mark in calculator

Tags: locale, language-support, calculator

In Germany we use `,` as decimal mark instead of `.`. Since I installed my Ubuntu in English, the Ubuntu default calculator (`gcalctool`) uses the `.` and I can't use the `,` on my German numpad.

I already set up German in `System Settings...`=>`Language Support`=>`Regional Formats` but it doesn't seem to set it for the calculator. I also saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209636/how-to-change-decimal-comma-to-decimal-period-in-numpad) but I want to avoid remapping my keys.

Can someone tell me if and how I can change this for the calculator or recommend a calculator that supports it?

Comment: @gertvdijk could have included that in my question ;-) Edited it now.

Comment: Do you see the `,` in the *Regional Formats* menu? I have the configuration like do you say and its working for me, [this is my config](http://i.imgur.com/sH0b0h0.png) and [this are my results](http://i.imgur.com/xJ09mSS.png)

Comment: @Lucio yes it looks exactly that way. I even clicked `Apply System-Wide`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes it's the easy things. Inspired by @Lucio who said that this should work I rebooted and it does now. Now I also saw that it says "`Changes take effect next time you log in.`". Read first, then ask. Should have done this in the first place, sorry for that!

So for everyone who wants to achieve the same:

- Go to `System Settings...`=>`Language Support`
- Make sure the language for your format locale is installed. You can install it using the `Install/Remove Languages` button
- Go to the `Regional Formats` tab and choose your country
- Click `Apply System-Wide`
- Reboot! (Or log out and back in. Should also work)

The default calculator should now accept the decimal mark used in your locale.

Comment: Good you found it. I think logging out and logging back in will also suffice.

Comment: Would be nice if there'd be a straightfwd way to *just* change the decimal mark (without affecting other stuff like date format)...