# Default keys "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" to input "! @ # $ % ^ & * ( )"

Tags: keyboard, special-characters, layout

Doing math homework on a full keyboard. Would like the top row to be the special characters without holding shift.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Keyboard layouts in Ubuntu are stored in */usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/*. The easiest way to get your desired result is to create a new layout by copying an existing one. Choose the one you are using at moment (you can have a look inside the files to find see the user friendly name of a layout). So for *English (US)* type

```
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us_math
```

into a terminal window. Now you have to edit the key specifications of the number keys. Open the file for editing, for example:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us_math
```

Search for the layout variant you are using, in the case of *English (US)* you will find it at the beginning of the file:

```
name[Group1]= "English (US)";
```

Change this text to:

```
name[Group1]= "English (math)";
```

Below you see the definition of the particular keys. Change (or insert, if you are using a variant that doesn't explicitly define these keys) the entires for keys *AE01* to *AE10*. In our example we would replace

```
key <AE01> {    [     1,    exclam      ]   };
key <AE02> {    [     2,    at      ]   };
key <AE03> {    [     3,    numbersign  ]   };
key <AE04> {    [     4,    dollar      ]   };
key <AE05> {    [     5,    percent     ]   };
key <AE06> {    [     6,    asciicircum ]   };
key <AE07> {    [     7,    ampersand   ]   };
key <AE08> {    [     8,    asterisk    ]   };
key <AE09> {    [     9,    parenleft   ]   };
key <AE10> {    [     0,    parenright  ]   };
```

by

```
key <AE01> {    [     exclam,   1   ]   };
key <AE02> {    [     at,       2   ]   };
key <AE03> {    [     numbersign,   3   ]   };
key <AE04> {    [     dollar,   4   ]   };
key <AE05> {    [     percent,  5   ]   };
key <AE06> {    [     asciicircum,  6   ]   };
key <AE07> {    [     ampersand,    7   ]   };
key <AE08> {    [     asterisk, 8   ]   };
key <AE09> {    [     parenleft,    9   ]   };
key <AE10> {    [     parenright,   0   ]   };
```

This will give you access to the special keys without using Shift and by Shift-ing you will be able to write numbers if you like to. Now edit anything else you like and save and close the file.
In the last step we will register the new keyboard layout with Gnome so you will be able to select it from the System settings.

Therefore open */usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/endev.xml* in the text editor of your choice, f.e.:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml
```

Find the text *<layoutList>* and insert the following description directly after it:

```
<layout>
  <configItem>
    <name>us_math</name>

    <shortDescription>en_math</shortDescription>
    <description>English (math)</description>
    <languageList>
      <iso639Id>eng</iso639Id>
    </languageList>
  </configItem>
</layout>
```

After saving the file you have to restart the X server. As Ctrl+Alt+Backspace didn't work on my system I restarted the system and was now able to select the new layout in *System Settings...* -> *Keyboard Layout*.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to System Settings > Keyboard
   [image]
2. Click on Layout Settings (button at bottom)

[image]

2. Select your layout in my case **English (US)** > Click **Options**
3. Hit the arrow on "Caps Lock Key behavior" > Then select "Caps Lock toggles Shift so all keys are affected"

[image]

Or, under "Miscellaneous compatibility options" you can check "Both Shift-Keys together toggle ShiftLock" if you want to keep the Caps Lock functioning the same, then you can press both Shift keys.

Comment: This is by far the easiest route as i _am_ only using it for math.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to harvest the `pretty screenshots` -- always a nice addition.

Answer (score 2):

in [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) , there is a general method to do what you're trying to do.

It'll be a bit of work, though.

In the end, the guy teaches you how to keep your changes after a reboot. You might want to skip the

```
Then you have to create a file called .xinitrc in your home directory [...]
```

and just run `xmodmap .Xmodmap` whenever you want the modified keyboard