# Typing Special characters without using shift key

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

How can I type special characters, without using the shift key?
 I have my numpad on the right of the keyboard, which I use for numbers.

I use the top row of my keyboard, only for symbols such as !,@,#,$, and so on.

Can I change settings such that I don't have to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>num</kbd> for typing these special characters, i.e I want to type `!` by pressing the key <kbd>1</kbd>, and not <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remap keyboard keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296155/how-can-i-remap-keyboard-keys)

Comment: Most of the answers are for F keys. I am not able to implement them for my situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default keys "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0" to input "! @ # $ % ^ & \* ( )"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/212336/default-keys-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-to-input)

Answer (score 0):

Use a text editor to edit the keyboard layout configuration file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us
```

change:

```
key <AE01> {        [         1,    exclam          ]       };
key <AE02> {        [         2,    at              ]       };
key <AE03> {        [         3,    numbersign      ]       };
key <AE04> {        [         4,    dollar          ]       };
key <AE05> {        [         5,    percent         ]       };
key <AE06> {        [         6,    asciicircum     ]       };
key <AE07> {        [         7,    ampersand       ]       };
key <AE08> {        [         8,    asterisk        ]       };
key <AE09> {        [         9,    parenleft       ]       };
key <AE10> {        [         0,    parenright      ]       };
```

to:

```
key <AE01> {        [             exclam          ]       };
key <AE02> {        [             at              ]       };
key <AE03> {        [             numbersign      ]       };
key <AE04> {        [             dollar          ]       };
key <AE05> {        [             percent         ]       };
key <AE06> {        [             asciicircum     ]       };
key <AE07> {        [             ampersand       ]       };
key <AE08> {        [             asterisk        ]       };
key <AE09> {        [             parenleft       ]       };
key <AE10> {        [             parenright      ]       };
```

Save the file and apply changes using this command:

```
setxkbmap us
```

*You might need to restart.*