# Swap F keys to perform functions without Fn key

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, keyboard-layout, swap

My laptop has a function key which turns <kbd>F</kbd> keys into keys which change volume or brightness. I would like to swap a number of them so that they perform that function under normal operation and are a function key while the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is being held.

I assumed that the function keys were just normal keys codes with the set of keys being large enough to include all the possible speical keys. I tried to so as this tutorial suggests ([How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)) and use `xev` to obtain the key codes and then would use `xmodmap` to swap their value.

This does not seem to work though. The <kbd>F12</kbd> key gives the `xev` output:

```
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
    root 0xb1, subw 0x0, time 468005, (23,-15), root:(89,37),
    state 0x10, keycode 96 (keysym 0xffc9, F12), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Which I think is to be expected. However, the Increase Volume button give this response:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  65  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And so does the Decrease Volume key. How can I perform the swapping of the keys that I would like?

Thank you

Comment: This option generally controlled by BIOS. Have you check there?

Answer (score 3):

Usually laptops have a setting in the BIOS which does this for you. When I got my laptop (an HP), it did this and I was able to change it. This is probably your best option.