# How to simulate keyboard input?

Tags: unity, wine, keyboard, shortcut-keys

This is the biggest thing keeping me from enjoying Ubuntu/Linux.

Ideally I'd like to just be able to run my AutoHotKey script on Ubuntu, but I didn't have much luck getting that working with Wine.

Here's what I'm doing in AHK (using extra modifiers also works, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>).

```
!l:: Send, {Right}
+!l:: Send, +{Right}
^!l:: Send, ^{Right}
^+!l:: Send, ^+{Right}
```

I tried AutoKey, but it wasn't consuming input, remapping <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to right arrow key worked, but it still executed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, which sometimes selects an item from the application menu.

The closest I got was `xbindkeys` for setting up hotkeys, this seems to work great. And `xvkbd` for simulating input; this part is really buggy; it doesn't work in all programs, and causes me to lose focus a lot, among other issues.

For anyone wondering what I'm trying to do: I use <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> as arrow keys while <kbd>Alt</kbd> is down.

Comment: Hey Stephen, i'm looking for exactly the same thing. Have you succeeded in doing this?

Answer (score 20):

I've never used xvkbd, but there are two other great programs for simulating keyboard input that I like and use. One is `xte` and the other is `xdotool`.

```
sudo apt-get install xautomation xdotool
```

Both `xdotool` and `xte` are very similar, but since I use `xte` the most I'll go into that one.

### xte:

The most basic syntax for `xte` is:

```
xte 'command key/mousebutton/xyCoordinates'
```

`xte` can do a lot more than just create keyboard input though, it can also move your mouse and simulate mouse button presses, among others things.

### Syntax examples:

- To call a single key press: `xte 'key keyName'`
- To call a key combination: `xte 'keydown keyName' 'keydown secondKeyName' 'keyup keyName' 'keyup secondKeyName`
- To call a mouse button: `xte 'mouseclick buttonNumber'` (You can find button numbers through `xev`)
- To move the mouse: `xte 'mousemove xCoordinate yCoordinate'`
- And more! Read `man xte`

### Keynames:

Here are a list of key names (other than the obvious ones):

```
Home
Left
Up
Right
Down
Page_Up
Page_Down
End
Return
BackSpace
Tab
Escape
Delete
Shift_L
Shift_R
Control_L
Control_R
Meta_L
Meta_R
Alt_L
Alt_R
Multi_key  
Super_L  
Super_R
```

### Reading:

You might also be interested in reading:

[How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do/)

[How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys/)

Comment: This looks good but it's not working with `xbindkeys`. When `xte 'key a'` is called from `xbindkeys` it just makes my cursor flash when I press my hotkey. `xte 'key a'` in the command line works. `gnome-terminal` called from `xbindkeys` works. I'm not sure where the problem is.

Comment: It really don't seem like `xte` is trying to send the key event to the focused window when called from `xbindkeys`...

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar I myself have had some trouble, but from my experience that has been `xbindkeys` problem.. For me I have to press the key combination at *exactly* the same time to get `xbindkeys` to send the command. YMMV.

Comment: Maybe an `xbindkeys` problem; `xdotool` worked with it, but when I held down a key, it would never repeat it. What are good alternatives to `xbindkeys`?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar Xmodmap is explained in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys/) answer as well as [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/257497/44179) one. That's what I'd use if `xbindkeys` didn't preform well enough (which it doesn't with xte.. at least for me.)

Comment: `xmodmap` only supports single buttons it looks like. I need to rebind `alt + i`