# Command to switch to tty1?

Tags: virtual-console

I want to make a list of commands to install everything so it's easier the next time I do it, however, I wanted one of the commands to do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for me.

Comment: Why would you want to switch to tty1 when you can just run the commands in a gnome terminal?

Comment: perhaps make it lock screen

Comment: @AndroidDev that's very close to the solution I was looking for, but I needed one that doesn't need sudo.

Comment: @ArM see the [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919558/518562) on that question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is quite simple actually. Just run this command:

```
sudo chvt 1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send keystrokes `xdotool` is the tool you need:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+Alt+F1
```

This will send the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as you requested, for other TTYs just change `F1`. You may need to install `xdotool` first with e.g.:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

---

*The following merely answers [How to programmatically trigger Ctrl+Alt+F1 without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963364/how-to-programmatically-trigger-ctrlaltf1-without-sudo), from where this answer was moved here.*

I find `osd_cat` (package `xosd-bin`) a fun way to notify myself, try:

```
echo alarm | osd_cat -Acenter -d10 -f"-adobe-helvetica-bold-*-*--400-*-*-*-*"
```

`-d` sets the time in seconds the notification is displayed, see [`man osd_cat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/osd_cat.1.html) for the many options.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done also via additional program as `xte` fron the package `xautomation`. Install the package:

```
sudo apt install -y xautomation
```

And run this command:

```
xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown Alt_L' 'key F1'
```

References:

- [How to simulate keyboard input?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/288114/how-to-simulate-keyboard-input)
- [How to send keystrokes (F5) from terminal to a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87831/how-to-send-keystrokes-f5-from-terminal-to-a-process)