# How to programmatically trigger Ctrl+Alt+F1 without sudo?

Tags: command-line, virtual-console

I was looking for a command which will allow me to trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>. This is so that I can invoke the command from the Alarm Clock app, which will ensure that I "notice" the alarm. I usually miss seeing any other window that pops up (tried xclock, etc.), and I've disabled sound, so whatever change occurs on the screen, it has to be prominent. I figured there'd be no way I was going to miss seeing the console, since it occupies the whole screen. Is there any command to trigger <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>? Ubuntu version: 16.04 LTS.

Edit: I need a solution that doesn't require `sudo`.