# How to switch to CLI mode

Tags: 22.04, shortcut-keys, windows, virtualization, tty

I am using MacBook M1 Pro and I have installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on UTM VM.
I want to use ubuntu in CLI mode how can I switch, like in windows we have an option **Ctlr Alt F3** and **Crtl Alt F1** to switch between CLI mode to GUI mode, I am unable to do that in my MacBook please guide me.

Regards,

Mohammed Arshad.

Comment: Doesn't Command (⌘) Alt F1 (or 2 or 3 or 4 etc) work?

Comment: No those commands doesn't work on my VM I am using UTM.

Comment: You'll have to look at your virtualization software settings to see how it handles special key combinations. Some have options to pass through, say, the left ctrl + left alt, and some have drop-down menus with options for various Ctrl+Alt key combos.

Comment: Or you can try commands like `chvt`: [Command to switch to tty1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919552/command-to-switch-to-tty1) -

Comment: Virtualbox has an on-screen-keyboard option. Something similar maybe there in your virtualization software

Comment: chvt 1 works for me but i have to login in to GUI mode first and then go to terminal and type command chvt 3 to switch to CLI mode. Is there any shortcut to direct I can login into CLI without logging in to GUI mode.