# How to assign a non working key to another key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My laptop's "m" key doesn't work anymore and I want to know how to re-map it. In example: to make it work with the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or any other key that I don't use that much.

Greetings.

P.S. Ubuntu is working normally but the "m" key is broken in my keyboard so I have to copy/paste it in order to write and it is tedious. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this has extensively been answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check XKeyCaps utility [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/xkeycaps/2.47-4).

XKeyCaps is a GUI application (a front end for [xmodmap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap)) which does exactly what you want to do with the help of an on screen keyboard where you can remap keys.

You can also find [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ34yW8qJrU) on YouTube runing the application on Ubuntu demonstrating its use.

Comment: be pleased your help, but when you start xkeycaps and choose the keyboard type mine is not on the list because it is a notebook PC keyboards only come look this --> http://i.imgbox.com/adtmVdf7.png

Comment: You can try some of the layouts to find a matching one.