# How can I assign Spanish characters on a French Canadian netbook keyboard

Tags: special-characters

I would like to assign

1. Alt Gr + n to type ñ
2. Alt Gr + i to type ¡
3. Alt Gr + g to type ¿

How can I program those key combinations?

Ubuntu 12.04, Mini Dell 9 netbook, French Canadian keyboard

Update: I found out about the compose key under Settings, Keyboard Layout, Options. I defined it under "caps lock". I can now type an ñ in pressing first caps lock, then pressing Alt Gr + ~ then pressing n.
I still don't know which key sequence I need to use to type an inverted exclamation '¡' or a question mark '¿'.
Can someone help for this one?

2nd update: I found out about the rest of my question.
I press once my defined Compose Key: Caps Lock, then I press Shift+1 twice to get '¡' and Shift+6 to get '¿'

The other topic regarding the same problem was not detailed enough. I hope mine is.

It would be nice to find a map of all possible characters produced with the compose key and the particular keyboard layout.

Comment: Does French Canadian layout support 'dead keys', i.e. AltGR + some other key (for accent/modificator), then letter, to make a non-standard accent? In Polish layout I've got Alt+], then 'n' for `ñ` etc. Some more info in http://spanish.about.com/od/writtenspanish/a/dia_ubuntu.htm

Answer (score 1):

Go to All Settings, Keyboard Layout, Options, Compose key position, choose one (I had to use Caps Lock because this is the one I use least).

Now if I click on Caps Lock then ss I get ß, or Caps lock =/ I get ≠, same for ñ, ¿ (??),¡ (!!), €, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

explains how to use xmodmap and xev to do that.
What about mapping then like:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 57 = n N n N ntilde"
xmodmap -e "keycode 31 = i I i I exclamdown"
xmodmap -e "keycode 42 = g G g G questiondown"
```

after that you can get the symbols that you want with the "alt Gr" key + n, i or g.