# Customize keyboard layout including navigation keys

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, navigation

I know how to customize the keyboard layout as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto:%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions). it works with symbols and numbers, but how can I assign navigation keys?

What I want to do is to assign the arrows and other navigation keys to use them with alt gr:

- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> = Left
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> = Down
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> = Right
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = Up
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> = Prev page
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> = Next page
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> = Home
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> = End
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> = Delete
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> = Escape
- <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> = Insert

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

and these changes did what I wanted. Now I can use the directions and numbers without moving my hands position.

First, run `xev` and press the keys to find their keycodes.

Create a script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

xmodmap -e "keycode 24 = q Q q Q Escape Escape"
xmodmap -e "keycode 25 = w W w W Delete Delete"
xmodmap -e "keycode 26 = e E e E Up Up"
xmodmap -e "keycode 27 = r R r R Prior Prior"
xmodmap -e "keycode 28 = t T t T Prior Prior"
xmodmap -e "keycode 29 = y Y"
xmodmap -e "keycode 30 = u U u U 7"
xmodmap -e "keycode 31 = i I i I 8"
xmodmap -e "keycode 32 = o O o O 9"
xmodmap -e "keycode 33 = p P"

xmodmap -e "keycode 38 = a A a A Home Home"
xmodmap -e "keycode 39 = s S s S Left Left"
xmodmap -e "keycode 40 = d D d D Down Down"
xmodmap -e "keycode 41 = f F f F Right Right"
xmodmap -e "keycode 42 = g G g G End End"
xmodmap -e "keycode 43 = h H"
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J j J 4"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K k K 5"
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L l L 6"
xmodmap -e "keycode 47 = semicolon colon"

xmodmap -e "keycode 52 = z Z z Z BackSpace BackSpace"
xmodmap -e "keycode 53 = x X x X Insert Insert"
xmodmap -e "keycode 54 = c C"
xmodmap -e "keycode 55 = v V v V Next Next"
xmodmap -e "keycode 56 = b B b B Next Next"
xmodmap -e "keycode 57 = n N n N 0"
xmodmap -e "keycode 58 = m M m M 1"
xmodmap -e "keycode 59 = comma less comma less 2"
xmodmap -e "keycode 60 = period greater period greater 3"
xmodmap -e "keycode 61 = slash question"
```

Give the script execution permissions with

```
sudo chmod 755 xmodmap.sh
```

To make this permanent, add this command to the startup applications:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 7 && /home/myusername/xmodmap.sh"
```