# How can I bind my capslock key to a fish shell command, and disable its toggle-caps functionality?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, fish

I have recently switched to fish shell, and its autocomplete is really nice.

However, I find myself wanting to use <kbd>tab</kbd> to use the complete_autocomplete feature, as opposed to when it's unambiguous. The forward and end keys both do this, but they're out of reach of my fingers in a normal typing position.

I would love to use the <kbd>Capslock</kbd> key for this, as I never ever use that key but it's in such a nice position.

I've tried `setxkbmap -option caps:none` but that seems to disable the <kbd>capslock</kbd> key entirely. I suppose I could bind it to the forward or end key but I'm not sure how to do this either.

Also, I can't seem to find a key binding in fish shell for <kbd>capslock</kbd>:

```
cowpig@gerty:~$ bind -K
b2
backspace
btab
dc
down
end
enter
f1
f2
f3
f4
f5
f6
f7
f8
f9
f10
f11
f12
f13
f14
f15
f16
f17
f18
f19
f20
home
ic
left
npage
ppage
right
sdc
send
sf
shome
sic
sleft
snext
sprevious
sr
sright
up
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to find a system-level remapping tool for Ubuntu, as user-land programs usually cant suppress default caps-lock behavior.

Comment: I guess you can use xbindkeys to set the default caps lock behaviour, tell it to send a different event, and handle that event in fish?

Comment: Does http://askubuntu.com/questions/574208/deactivate-caps-lock-in-14-04 help?

Comment: Possibly related:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/82837/how-do-i-make-the-caps-lock-key-a-third-shift-key/820421#820421

Comment: You might be able to write a Python daemon to handle this. Some basic info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367358/listening-for-global-key-combinations-in-python-on-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check the manual because I think that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will also autocomplete. You can see it typing `help` in fish.

If you want to go ahead with the mapping, run `xev` and press <kbd>capslock</kbd> to get the keycode. Mine is 66:

```
enter code hereKeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5200001,
root 0x4b7, subw 0x0, time 6149967, (918,609), root:(984,661),
state 0x10, keycode 66 (keysym 0xff57, End), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Now create a script (i.e. ~/xmodmap.sh) with permission 755 and the following text:

```
#/bin/bash
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = End"
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
```

Run the script and it will convert the <kbd>capslock</kbd> into the <kbd>End</kbd> key.

To make this permanent, add this command to the startup applications:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 7 && /home/myusername/xmodmap.sh"
```

I've tried it with the fish shell and it does auto complete the command.

I use <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> to map some keys to closer positions: [Customize keyboard layout including navigation keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339772/customize-keyboard-layout-including-navigation-keys/349143#349143)

Comment: This is ALMOST what I want :)