# Script to automate remapping keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, scripts

When I use Windows I currently use AutoHotKey to re-map keys (I swapped keyboards on my laptop).

Is there any way I can do this in Ubuntu via a script which I can just double-click from the desktop? Or can AutoHotKey/anything similar be used on Ubuntu?

Any example is most welcome- say remap the insert key to the home key?

Answer (score 1):

[How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

If you want you can set the line on startup apps so you dont have to do it every time you turn on your computer.