# How do I enter the Euro symbol?

Tags: keyboard

I have a US English keyboard. How do I enter a euro symbol in Ubuntu? I can't find the symbol in character map, and I don't really want to change keyboard layout just to type one symbol occasionally.

Comment: You can check the **US with euro on 5** keyboard layout.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Ubuntu and the only explanation that works is the changes in terminal, however, each time the computer is restarted it reverts to the old setting.
The further explanation to make it permanent is not clearly described and needs to be expanded- remembering that we are not all at the same level :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In **Character Map**, select **Common**.

[image]

Comment: Better methods if you need to do this often: learn about compose Key that let you do it pressing 3 key <compose_key> e =

Comment: in Ubuntu 16 the compose key method should be the recommended method.

Answer (score 78):

If you use **English (US)** keyboard layout and you don't want to change it, the the fastest way would be to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> key combination and then type `20ac` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd>(or <kbd>Enter</kbd>) which will turn into `€`.

---

Now if you want, *for example*, to change the `$` sign (which you can type it using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> shortcut when you have an US English keyboard) with `€` sign, you can use the following command in terminal in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  13 = 4 EuroSign 4 EuroSign"
```

From now you can type `€` using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> shortcut.

To switch back to `$` sign, use:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar"
```

To get this change for every session, create a file called `.xmodmap`, with the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```

In the same mode you can set any other key combination to type `€` symbol. Use `xmodmap -pke` command to see all keycodes and their map assignment.

Comment: For more information on xmodmap read the following answer  http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices, and other unicode characters see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Excellent, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: xmodmap won't work in recent Ubuntu versions. Unfortunately.

Comment: in Ubuntu 16, the compose key method is superior to tweaking a system or remember codes.

Comment: @axd For those of us coming from Windows, where we learned (over time) Alt+0128 = € or Alt+130 = é, the first section of this answer is great. Remember, some of us have an easier time remembering numbers than others. Everybody is different.

Answer (score 70):

**Method 1) Use the compose key.**

Compose key sequences for €

<kbd>compose key</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

or
<kbd>compose key</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>

In fact, you can type the characters following the compose key in either order.

So
<kbd>compose key</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>
or
<kbd>compose key</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> also work.

**To set the compose key in 13.10,**

1. Go to *System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts* or *System Settings >> Text Entry >> Keyboard Settings*.
2. Choose *Typing* in the left column.
3. Click *Compose Key* and choose an option from the pop-up list. *Right-Alt* is a common choice.

**To set the compose key in earlier versions,**

1. Go to *System Settings >> Keyboard Layout >> Options*.
2. Click *Compose Key Position* to expand the list of options.

Compose key options are hard-coded in Gnome-based systems. See [the Gtk compose key table](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable).

**Method 2) Use the Alternative Characters Key** (also called the 3rd level chooser in earlier versions

This way is a little more complicated to set up, but will give you a 2-character sequence.

This requires `dconf-editor`. `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

1. From the *Shortcuts >> Typing* as above, click *Alternative Characters Key*, and choose an option from the pop-up. (You do not have to set the compose key to use this option, but if you set it, make sure the compose key and alternative characters are set to different keys.)
2. In `dconf-editor`, navigate to *org >> gnome >> desktop >> input-sources*
3. To the setting `xkb-options` add one of the following:

   `'eurosign:e'`
   `'eurosign:2'`
   `'eurosign:4'`
   `'eurosign:5'`

The single-quotes are required. If you already have options listed, separate strings with commas.

For example, I have the compose key set to `right-alt`, the alternative character set to `menu`, and euro set to 4. The setting looks like this:

```
['eurosign:4','lv3:menu_switch','compose:ralt']
```

The order of the strings doesn't matter. You can see that I chose the menu key and put the euro symbol on 4.

Now, <kbd>alternative char key</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> produces `€`.

Comment: `compose key` + `C` + `=` (or the other way around) also works. Nice memonic!

Comment: The compose key idea is excellent. Very intuitive—I think € is the first one I've had to look up. My intuition was reaching for `compose key`+`$`+`e`

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 Macbook pro with US keyboard.  In Settings > Languages and Regions, I use the input source English(US, intl., with dead key) to type various European scripts with diacritics.  The compose key is the right command key and works nicely as explained above to produce €.

Comment: This is the only answer on the entire Internet that worked for me, and I searched for a good 30 minutes.

Comment: It doesn't work for Ubuntu 22.04 with US keyboard layout. Compose+c+= gives the copyright symbol. Compose+e+= gives nothing.

Comment: compose key is my new best friend

Answer (score 14):

**On my **UK** keyboard, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> = €**
PS:If you use a compose key (I use Win+Right) then I can use "="+"e"  but no need in doing that since the first method described here is easier
I stress again this is on a UK keyboard layout.

Comment: Does not work for me on US and LT keyboards.

Comment: Thanks, on my system you get the `€` system with `alt gr + 5`, but only when typing in Greek. When typing in English it does not work.

Comment: @ViliusK on LT keyboard Alt Gr + e works

Comment: Yes, @RytisAlekna, that works.

Comment: This works and is the best shortest answer. Works with unity 7.5 ubuntu 20.04 even. :)

Comment: You need to specify which keyboard LAYOUT you use, not the actual type of keyboard you have. US Intl or US (€ on 5) will both allow you to type € by pressing `RIGHT-ALT + 5` or `ALT GR + 5`, depending on the keyboard you have.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of the standard `English (US)` keyboard, switch to the `English (US, alternative international)` keyboard and you'll get the <kbd>€</kbd> under <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and you'll be able to type most Western-European languages, including Français, Español, Italiano (Pasta al ragù), Nederlands (zeeën), Deutsch (Doppelgänger), ...

Here's the keyboard layout:

[image]

**Note:** <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is the right <kbd>Alt</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

This is a way to enter any Unicode character, especially for those with no <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key.

Press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and type Unicode sequence:
`20AC`

Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and a '€' symbol will appear.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> = €                              .

Comment: it's not the same (E≠5) and it works om my US layout

Comment: What if keyboard has no `Alt Gr`?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to find the keyboard layout contained in [@fabby's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/676018/652) above. To do that in Ubuntu 15.10, tap the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to show the Finder, search for and open `keyboard`, click the `text entry` link, then the little `keyboard` icon underneath the keyboard sources box in the window that appears:

[image: the window that appears].

You will then see the keyboard layout for your own configuration:

[image: keyboard layout for your own configuration]

and should be able to find the € sign or any other special character you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the best two choices (on Linux Mint 20) are:

**English (US, alt. intl.)**

- sets € under AltGr + 5 and AltGr + e
- sets ¢ under AltGr + Shift + e
- sets quotes and such to need an extra **<space>** to form

**English (US, euro on 5)**

- set € under AltGr + 5
- doesn't have the ¢ option
- doesn't set quotes and such to need an extra **<space>** to form

Comment: LM is not Ubuntu, it is off topic here.

Comment: Yeah, I doubted it a bit, but the other information here worked for me, and Mint is based on Ubuntu. And I'm guessing this is more about the type of keyboards. So seemed useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 , the shortcut is: <kbd>AltGr</kbd>(right Alt) + <kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

On an Ubuntu 13.10 Macbook Air 2013 with an English (Mac) keyboard, the shortcut is

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

It is simple on my Lubuntu 18.04 keyboard, AltGr + 4 does it. Also AltGR + c gives ¢ which serves well enough for Euro cents.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 for the European languages, the shortcut is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> = €