# How to make hotkeys ALT_L+X and ALT_R+Y different in KDE?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, keyboard-layout

In KDE settings pressing left and right modifier keys have no difference, for example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> works both with left and right <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys. Is it possible to make them different?

Using xev you can see that these keys produce different events, so it's the KDE question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has answered this, I'll try to give you a few clues as to where to look as I don't know the answer myself.

I have seen posts on it before, so I had some idea of what to look for.

(This would be way too ugly to put into a comment.)

Look into X tools including xdotool and the .xbindkeysrc

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80660/how-to-remap-a-key-combination-to-a-key/81178#81178

xmodmap

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90919/map-a-symbol-to-a-specific-key

[How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

The Linux keyboard and console HOWTO

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.pdf