# .xinitrc with keyboard mapping not working

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10. When I remap keys using xmodmap using the instructions at [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys) , the remapping works fine. But when I create the .xinitrc file as a plain text file with `xmodmap .Xmodmap` in the home folder, and restart the computer, I still lose the changes. I've also tried `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` but that made no difference. When I simply run `xmodmap .Xmodmap` in the command after booting, it does work. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make a script, to run each time you login.

- Create an empty .sh file
- Input your code inside. It can look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is my remapping to change AltGr with W. Edit it to work with yours.
sleep 25
xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_R"
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = w W Cyrillic_ve Cyrillic_VE"
```

- Make it executable.
- Add it to Application Autostart tab of Session and Startup.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating `.xsessionrc` instead. `.xinitrc` is only used by xinit, I believe - when X is started by a display manager like lightdm or gdm, I don't think it is sourced.