# Enable repeat for a specific key

Tags: xorg, keyboard

My <kbd>↓</kbd> key has died tonight. While waiting for a new keyboard, I am using the answer here to map the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (key code 105) so that it acts as <kbd>↓</kbd>:

[How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

Long story short:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 105 = Down"
```

I then enabled repeat:

```
xset r 105
```

This last command seems to work in some cases (this very input box), but not many others (repeat won't work for scroll down in Chrome, nor in the terminal input.

Any hints on why?