# Left Alt key should work as right Alt key (Alt Gr)

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I'm using a German Apple keyboard on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Under Mac OS X the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key has the same behavior as the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (I think the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key acts as the <kbd>AltGr</kbd>).
I don't know what I must remove from the mapping to clear the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and what I must add that the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key acts the same way as the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

My questions are:

- How can I get the current mapping of the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?
- And how can I assign it to the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key?

Comment: Could I ask why you want that? all shortcut with ALT key will not work, because there will be no Alt key if both configured as AltGr.

Comment: @user.dz One would of course want that in order to continue using Left Alt as a modifier for writing symbols like `@`, `|`, `«`. or `»`. I don't want to have to relearn to use the Right Alt key for that.

Comment: try this answer here("https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices")

Comment: this depends on your keyboard layout. I experienced this problem because I was using Italian/European Keyboard Layout. If you switch to US layout, alt gr is replaced with alt key

Answer (score 7):

### Swapping <kbd>Left ALT</kbd> & <kbd>Right ALT</kbd> functions

1. The following command will set:

   - <kbd>Left ALT</kbd>  as level3-switch or <kbd>ALT Gr</kbd>
   - <kbd>Right ALT</kbd> as normal-alt or <kbd>ALT</kbd>

   _

   `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt']"`

   Effective immediately.
2. To reset it:

   `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

   or `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"`

**Notes:**

- To see all available options for all modifier keys make a look on `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst`
- There are other hacks, I don't recommend. Like changing line `include "level3(ralt_switch)"` or swapping key codes in X11/xkb layout files.

Comment: When I do that, the Right Alt key works the same as the Left Alt one (i.e., I cannot `Alt-Tab` anymore, or keyboard shortcuts that require `Alt` do not work).

Comment: @slhck Yes, by default making a key as layout level switch will disable it from modifier setup. Otherwise, you get a weird actions, lalt+a will activate menu and insert a with accent. :/. AFAIK xkb does not support multiple actions for short and long press.

Comment: @slhck the original answer is exactly asking for that: "My questions are how can I get the current mapping of the right Alt key and assign it to the left Alt key?"
If you have a different question, please a new question.

Comment: @danzel I understand there is a slight difference between simply mapping Right Alt to Left Alt, but you still need the functionality of Left Alt available *somewhere* in order to properly use the OS. With the given constraints I guess that this answer is the best one.

Answer (score 2):

First, select **`System Settings`** :

[image: Screenshot 1: open System Settings]

Select **Keyboard Layout** from the presented window :

[image: Screenshot 2: select "Keyboard Layout"]

You will be presented with a list of all available layouts. Just press the <kbd>Options</kbd> button:

[image: Screenshot 3: click "Options"]

Lastly, from the presented list  select **`Alt/Win key behavior`** and modify to your needs:

[image: Screenshot 4: "Alt/Win key behavior" list]

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Perhaps a look at [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Howto%3a%20Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions) will be more helpful.

Comment: I came back to this (unfortunately unsolved) issue, now I placed a bounty on the question. Unfortunately the options you showed do not include a control for swapping Left and Right Alt.

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 18:04**

gnome tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level -> Any Alt

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I found the answer fot it!

You simply have to open `gnome tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level -> Right Alt never chooses 3rd level` and your right alt works the same way left alt does.

If you really want a 3rd grade button you still can choose any other option like right win or menu button for example.

I personally like to use the menu button as my alt grade and it makes much more sense since I don't use this button.

Answer (score 0):

Right Alt is often used as the [Compose Key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) so it may have been mapped to that function. You might solve your problem by looking closely in your system settings, under Hardware > Keyboard (not Personal > Keyboard Layout). Under the shortcuts tab, check and see if Right Alt is used as a shortcut to anything. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsXOz.png) of what that menu looks like on my system, where I've mapped it as the Compose Key.

[image]

Comment: Did that solve your issue, @slhck ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have Caps Lock set as my compose key. I do not even know how to get to this window that you're showing.

Comment: Perhaps it's a little different in 12.04 than it is on my 14.04 machine. It's the option in the upper right of the first image on this page: http://www.techdrivein.com/2012/03/ubuntu-1204-features-new-easily.html

Comment: I am using 18.04 now so that's why, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

I used the process described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/446788/), but instead of "Alt/Win key behavior", I found "Keys Level 3" and checked "Every key alt"

[image]

(My Linux is in French, sorry for my poor translation)