# Remap several key: Alt_L key to have the same behavior as Alt_R (or Alt gr) + remap caps lock to escape

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, remapping, keycodes

I want to change the behavior of the Alt_L key on my keyboard (keycode 64) so that it has the same behavior as the Alt_R (keycode 108 or Alt gr) on Ubuntu 22.04.

the output of the following command `xmodmap -pke` is the following

```
keycode  64 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

I read the following pages

https://superuser.com/questions/53092/gnome-map-altgr-key-to-alt
[How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/257497#257497)

and try the following commands:

```
xmodmap -e "clear Alt_L"
xmodmap -e "keycode 64 = ISO_Level3_Shift"
```

First I get the following error message:

```
xmodmap:  commandline:1:  bad clear modifier name 'alt_l'
xmodmap:  1 error encountered, aborting.
```

I then re-run the following command `xmodmap -pke` with the following output

```
keycode  64 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
keycode 108 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

So to me it seems that the key was successfully remapped, however, the behaviour does not change

I saw that there was a very similar question in which some comments seem to indicate that it could be related to a bug

[Ubuntu+1: How to map ALT Gr key as ALT R on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226777/ubuntu1-how-to-map-alt-gr-key-as-alt-r-on-ubuntu-20-04)

**EDIT 1**

I also saw the following question

[Left Alt key should work as right Alt key (Alt Gr)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446778/left-alt-key-should-work-as-right-alt-key-alt-gr)

As I want to remap caps lock to escape, I used the combination of those commands:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:escape']" 
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt']"
```

and

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt']"
```

however, with the 2 last solutions, only the last command is effective but the first one does not work

**EDIT 2**
According to this question, it is not possible to use xmodmap in Ubuntu anymore:
[Permanent xmodmap in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325272/permanent-xmodmap-in-ubuntu-13-04)

If this is the case it is rather sad because it is then not possible to use troubleshooting tool such as `xev`

How could I solve the problem?

**partial answer**

What worked for me was to put the three commands in the same line :

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt', 'caps:escape']"
```

However that does not solve the important question about how to use `xev` for trouble shooting