# Using dconf write or gsettings set several times overwrite the previous command

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, dconf, gsettings, remapping

I would like to remap several different keys of my keyboard.Namely: I want to remap caps Lock to escape function and remap left alt to right alt function. For this I used the following commands:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['caps:escape']" 
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt']"
```

Using `gsettings set` instead of `dconf write` has the same effect:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:escape']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt']"
```

As mentionned in a similar question ([Remap several key: Alt_L key to have the same behavior as Alt_R (or Alt gr) + remap caps lock to escape](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1470606/remap-several-key-alt-l-key-to-have-the-same-behavior-as-alt-r-or-alt-gr-re)), the first command seems to be overwritten by the second one.

How is it possible to have those 2 commands effective at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was easy: it was just needed to put the 3 commands in the same line ... ;):

```
 dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['lv3:lalt_switch','lv3:ralt-alt', 'caps:escape']"
```