# Trying to map <Ctrl>+<hjkl> to <Left Down Up Right> globally (Vim-like arrow keys) with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, vim, xmodmap

I am trying to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> to arrow keys <kbd>Left</kbd>,<kbd>Down</kbd>,<kbd>Up</kbd>,<kbd>Right</kbd>, respectively, on Ubuntu OS (globally, not inside Vim).

I've attempted the solution posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys/24930#24930?newreg=4ecc14e0409c4ec0837b98b9806a829a), but the modifier commands are not working. Here is what I am trying:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 Control_L = k Up"
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 control = k Up"
```

(keycode 45 maps to `K`)

Neither commands work. (They give no errors, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is not remapped to <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>)

Is there a way to do this xmodmap, and if not, is there a cleaner workaround?

Thanks!

Edit: I have found my answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/96299/mapping-superhjkl-to-arrow-keys-under-x) - thanks to swift

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is surely very strange idea to turn Ubuntu into the codename "VimOS". I think much more adequate to map Vim's keys to some free and equable more cluster of the keyboard. Or definitely NOT due to it is also might be useful.

However I do not deletes my first suggest about Vim mappings and should to say that answer to your question exist here:
[**System wide vim-style (hjkl) navigation**](http://shellhell.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/hello-world/)

Partially I agree this view (thanks to **shell hell**):

> <sub>NOTE 3: Setting up <kbd>Ctrl / Meta</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>,<kbd>J</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> keybindings seems to be simplest
>   way to have vim-style navigation but it’s not. First: you would have
>   to do this on per application basis which is tiresome process. Second:
>   you’ll probably end up breaking default mappings for any given
>   application. Last but not least: some apps e.g. rtorrent or htop don’t
>   let you change their defaults, save by patching their sourcecode. For
>   similar reasons you won’t get job done with <kbd>Super / Hyper</kbd>, either.</sub>

And also I found near answer here:
[**Superuser: Mapping Super+hjkl to arrow keys under X**](https://superuser.com/questions/96299/mapping-superhjkl-to-arrow-keys-under-x)

Vim uses a switching modes to mapping keys. So xmodmap for Vim it is some pluggable globals what breaks classic Vim experience. Even so to claim it sounds pathetic <sub>`;)`</sub>

> Vim supports several editing modes - normal, insert, replace, visual,
>   select, command-line and operator-pending. You can map a key to work
>   in all or some of these modes.

[Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 1)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29)
[Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 2)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29)
[Mapping keys in Vim - Tutorial (Part 3)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_3%29)

Comment: Hi swift, thanks for the reply. Perhaps I was unclear in asking my question. I am not attempting to do any key remaps inside of Vim. I'm actually trying to map ctrl+hjkl to arrow keys-left, down, up, right, respectively, on my GNU/Linux Ubuntu distribution. The post I linked claims that this is possible (indirectly), but I am unable to achieve this successfully.

Comment: sorry, I understood your first edition not right. ok, will update answer )

Comment: VimOS! Where do I get it?

Comment: Make it from xmonad! 

Answer (score 2):

I have Tux-J and Tux-K mapped to Up and Down in KDE, it is relevant for all applications. It is actually rather easy to configure.

1. Go here: `System Settings -> Custom Shorcuts -> Preset Actions`
2. Now right-click `Preset Actions` and choose `New -> Global Shortcut -> Send Keyboard Input`
3. Call the new shortcut `VIM-J`
4. In the Trigger tab click the Shortcut button and them press <kbd>Tux</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd>.
5. In the Action tab enter `Down`
6. At the bottom of the window click `Apply`.
7. Check that the shortcut works. If so, then configure the remaining HK and L keys.

**Enjoy!**