# bind Super key to control key Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, compiz

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. I can't find the option to bind Super key to control key. I did the same on Ubuntu 12.04 where the option is given in Keyboard settings. Is there a way  to achieve similar thing in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys Should have the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have installed `Tweak tool` install it and open it. In the `Typing` section you will see `Alt/Win behavior` and you can select `Ctrl is mapped to Win keys`. I think that's what you're looking for.