# Numeric pad always enter digits

Tags: kde, qt-creator

In KDE there is an option to keep number work as if it is on:

[image]
.

But it does not work in edit area of Qt Creator. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not a duplicate as that solution does not work here.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this

```
setxkbmap -option numpad:mac
```

If it works, [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1222529#p1222529) is how to make it permanent.

As this didn't work, another suggestion: 
Use XModmap to remap numpad key to only a digit. Xmodmap manual [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys/24930#24930). If that will not work, I give up.

Comment: In Qt Creator it does not work.

Comment: I gave another suggestion.

Comment: It's simpler to edit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/. btw I don't know where are the numpad keys.

Comment: Xmodmap does not require editing system files.

Answer (score 1):

I changed `keypad‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌` file located in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` to

```
partial hidden keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "overlay" {
    include "keypad(overlay1)"
};

partial hidden keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "overlay1" {

    key  <KP7> {    [  KP_7 ],  overlay1=<KO7>  }; // 1: KP_Home
    key  <KP8> {    [  KP_8 ],  overlay1=<KO8>  }; // 1: KP_Up
    key  <KP9> {    [  KP_9 ],  overlay1=<KO9>  }; // 1: KP_Prior

    key  <KP4> {    [  KP_4 ],  overlay1=<KO4>  }; // 1: KP_Left
    key  <KP5> {    [  KP_5 ],  overlay1=<KO5>  }; // 1: KP_Begin
    key  <KP6> {    [  KP_6 ],  overlay1=<KO6>  }; // 1: KP_Right

    key  <KP1> {    [  KP_1 ],  overlay1=<KO1>  }; // 1: KP_End
    key  <KP2> {    [  KP_2 ],  overlay1=<KO2>  }; // 1: KP_Down
    key  <KP3> {    [  KP_3 ],  overlay1=<KO3>  }; // 1: KP_Next

    key  <KP0> {    [  KP_0 ],  overlay1=<KO0>  }; // 2: KP_Insert
    key <KPDL> {    [  KP_Decimal   ],  overlay1=<KODL> }; // 2: KP_Delete

    key  <KO7> {    [  KP_7 ]   };
    key  <KO8> {    [  KP_8 ]   };
    key  <KO9> {    [  KP_9 ]   };

    key  <KO4> {    [  KP_4 ]   };
    key  <KO5> {    [  KP_5 ]   };
    key  <KO6> {    [  KP_6 ]   };

    key  <KO1> {    [  KP_1 ]   };
    key  <KO2> {    [  KP_2 ]   };
    key  <KO3> {    [  KP_3 ]   };

    key  <KO0> {    [  KP_0 ]   };
    key <KODL> {    [  KP_Decimal ] };
};

partial hidden keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "overlay2" {

    key  <KP7> {    [  KP_7 ],  overlay2=<KO7>  }; // 1: KP_Home
    key  <KP8> {    [  KP_8 ],  overlay2=<KO8>  }; // 1: KP_Up
    key  <KP9> {    [  KP_9 ],  overlay2=<KO9>  }; // 1: KP_Prior

    key  <KP4> {    [  KP_4 ],  overlay2=<KO4>  }; // 1: KP_Left
    key  <KP5> {    [  KP_5 ],  overlay2=<KO5>  }; // 1: KP_Begin
    key  <KP6> {    [  KP_6 ],  overlay2=<KO6>  }; // 1: KP_Right

    key  <KP1> {    [  KP_1 ],  overlay2=<KO1>  }; // 1: KP_End
    key  <KP2> {    [  KP_2 ],  overlay2=<KO2>  }; // 1: KP_Down
    key  <KP3> {    [  KP_3 ],  overlay2=<KO3>  }; // 1: KP_Next

    key  <KP0> {    [  KP_0 ],  overlay2=<KO0>  }; // 1: KP_Insert
    key <KPDL> {    [  KP_Decimal   ],  overlay2=<KODL> }; // 1: KP_Delete

    key  <KO7> {    [  KP_7 ]   };
    key  <KO8> {    [  KP_8 ]   };
    key  <KO9> {    [  KP_9 ]   };

    key  <KO4> {    [  KP_4 ]   };
    key  <KO5> {    [  KP_5 ]   };
    key  <KO6> {    [  KP_6 ]   };

    key  <KO1> {    [  KP_1 ]   };
    key  <KO2> {    [  KP_2 ]   };
    key  <KO3> {    [  KP_3 ]   };

    key  <KO0> {    [  KP_0 ]   };
    key <KODL> {    [  KP_Decimal ] };
};

partial hidden keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "operators" {
    // Puts some commands to control the X server on
    // the fifth level of the keypad's operator keys.
    key <KPDV> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",    // Ungrab cancels server/keyboard/pointer grabs
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Divide, KP_Divide, KP_Divide, KP_Divide, XF86_Ungrab ]
    };
    key <KPMU> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",    // ClsGrb kills whichever client has a grab in effect
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, XF86_ClearGrab ]
    };
    key <KPSU> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",    // -VMode switches to the previous video mode
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, XF86_Prev_VMode ]
    };
    key <KPAD> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",    // +VMode switches to the next video mode
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Add, KP_Add, KP_Add, KP_Add, XF86_Next_VMode ]
    };
};

default  partial hidden keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "x11" {

    include "keypad(operators)"

    key  <KP7> {    [  KP_7,    KP_7    ]   }; // 1: KP_Home
    key  <KP8> {    [  KP_8,    KP_8    ]   }; // 1: KP_Up
    key  <KP9> {    [  KP_9,    KP_9    ]   }; // 1: KP_Prior

    key  <KP4> {    [  KP_4,    KP_4    ]   }; // 1: KP_Left
    key  <KP5> {    [  KP_5,    KP_5    ]   }; // 1: KP_Begin
    key  <KP6> {    [  KP_6,    KP_6    ]   }; // 1: KP_Right

    key  <KP1> {    [  KP_1,    KP_1    ]   }; // 1: KP_End
    key  <KP2> {    [  KP_2,    KP_2    ]   }; // 1: KP_Down
    key  <KP3> {    [  KP_3,    KP_3    ]   }; // 1: KP_Next
    key <KPEN> {    [   KP_Enter    ]   };
    key <KPEQ> {    [   KP_Equal    ]   };

    key  <KP0> {    [  KP_0,    KP_0    ]   }; // 1: KP_Insert
    key <KPDL> {    [  KP_Decimal,  KP_Decimal ]    }; // 1: KP_Delete
    key <KPPT> {    [  KP_Decimal,  KP_Decimal ]    };
};


// Legacy PC keypad definition
// Copyright © 2006-2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "legacy" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(legacymath)"
    include "keypad(legacynumber)"
    include "kpdl(dot)"
};


// Legacy Wang 725-3771-ae and 725-3771-uk keypad definition
// Copyright © 2006-2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "legacy_wang" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(legacymath)"
    include "keypad(legacynumber_wang)"
    include "kpdl(dot)"
};


// Complete new keypad definition
// Copyright © 2006-2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "oss" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(ossmath)"
    include "keypad(ossnumber)"
    include "kpdl(dotoss)"
};


// Latin9 restriction of new keypad definition
// Copyright © 2006-2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "oss_latin9" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(ossmath_latin9)"
    include "keypad(legacynumber)"
    include "kpdl(dotoss_latin9)"
};


// Wang 725-3771-ae and 725-3771-uk keypad variant of oss keypad
// Copyright © 2006-2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "oss_wang" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(ossmath)"
    include "keypad(ossnumber_wang)"
    include "kpdl(dotoss)"
};


// Forward-looking keypad definition
// Won't work with applications that make ASCII assumptions
// Copyright © 2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "future" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(futuremath)"
    include "keypad(ossnumber)"
    include "kpdl(commaoss)"
};


// Forward-looking keypad definition
// Won't work with applications that make ASCII assumptions
// Copyright © 2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "future_wang" {

    include "keypad(core)"
    include "keypad(futuremath)"
    include "keypad(ossnumber_wang)"
    include "kpdl(commaoss)"
};


// Keypad keys nobody changes
// Copyright © 2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "core" {

    modifier_map Mod2 { Num_Lock };

    key <NMLK> { [ Num_Lock, Pointer_EnableKeys ] };
    key <KPEN> { [ KP_Enter                     ] };
    key <KPEQ> { [ KP_Equal                     ] };
};


// Legacy keypad math area
// Copyright © 2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱─────┬─────┬─────┐
// ┃Num  ┃ ₁   │ ₂   │ ₃   │ ₁ <XF86_Ungrab>
// ┃Lock⇭┃ /   │ *   │ -   │ ₂ <XF86_ClearGrab>
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼─────┤ ₃ <XF86_Prev_VMode>
//                   │ ₄   │ ₄ <XF86_Next_VMode>
//                   │     │
//                   ┤     │ 1 None
//                   │     │ 2 Ctrl+Alt
//                   │ +   │
//                   ╆━━━━━┪
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "legacymath" {

    key.type[Group1]="CTRL+ALT" ;

    key <KPDV> { [   KP_Divide, KP_Divide, KP_Divide, KP_Divide, XF86_Ungrab ] }; // / <XF86_Ungrab>
    key <KPMU> { [ KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, XF86_ClearGrab ] }; // * <XF86_ClearGrab>
    key <KPSU> { [ KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, XF86_Prev_VMode ] }; // - <XF86_Prev_VMode>

    key <KPAD> { [      KP_Add, KP_Add, KP_Add, KP_Add, XF86_Next_VMode ] }; // + <XF86_Next_VMode>
};


// Keypad math area with non-CS operators
// Copyright © 2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱─────┬─────┬─────┐
// ┃Num  ┃ ∕ ₁ │ . ₂ │ − ₃ │ ₁ <XF86_Ungrab>
// ┃Lock⇭┃ / ÷ │ * × │ - − │ ₂ <XF86_ClearGrab>
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼─────┤ ₃ <XF86_Prev_VMode>
//                   │ + ₄ │ ₄ <XF86_Next_VMode>
//                   │     │
//                   ┤     │ 1 None
//                   │     │ 2 Level3 ⇮
//                   │ + + │ 3 Shift+Level3 ⇧⇮
//                   ╆━━━━━┪ 4 Ctrl+Alt
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "ossmath" {

    key.type[Group1]="CTRL+ALT" ;

    key <KPDV> { [   KP_Divide, 0x1002215, 0x10000F7, VoidSymbol,     XF86_Ungrab ] }; // / ∕ ÷     <XF86_Ungrab>
    key <KPMU> { [ KP_Multiply, 0x10022C5, 0x10000D7, VoidSymbol,  XF86_ClearGrab ] }; // * ⋅ ×  <XF86_ClearGrab>
    key <KPSU> { [ KP_Subtract, 0x1002212, 0x1002212, VoidSymbol, XF86_Prev_VMode ] }; // - − − <XF86_Prev_VMode>

    key <KPAD> { [      KP_Add, 0x100002B, 0x100002B, VoidSymbol, XF86_Next_VMode ] }; // + + + <XF86_Next_VMode>
};


// Keypad math area with non-CS operators in first levels
// As demanded by users not interested in legacy pre-unicode junk
// Copyright © 2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱─────┬─────┬─────┐
// ┃Num  ┃ / ₁ │ * ₂ │ - ₃ │ ₁ <XF86_Ungrab>
// ┃Lock⇭┃ ∕ ÷ │ . × │ − − │ ₂ <XF86_ClearGrab>
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼─────┤ ₃ <XF86_Prev_VMode>
//                   │ + ₄ │ ₄ <XF86_Next_VMode>
//                   │     │
//                   ┤     │ 1 None
//                   │     │ 2 Level3 ⇮
//                   │ + + │ 3 Shift+Level3 ⇧⇮
//                   ╆━━━━━┪ 4 Ctrl+Alt
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "futuremath" {

    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_X" ;

    key <KPDV> { [ 0x1002215,   KP_Divide, 0x10000F7,     XF86_Ungrab ] }; // ∕ / ÷     <XF86_Ungrab>
    key <KPMU> { [ 0x10022C5, KP_Multiply, 0x10000D7,  XF86_ClearGrab ] }; // ⋅ * ×  <XF86_ClearGrab>
    key <KPSU> { [ 0x1002212, KP_Subtract, 0x1002212, XF86_Prev_VMode ] }; // − - − <XF86_Prev_VMode>

    key <KPAD> { [ 0x100002B,      KP_Add, 0x100002B, XF86_Next_VMode ] }; // + + + <XF86_Next_VMode>
};


// Keypad math area with non-CS operators, restricted to latin9
// Copyright © 2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱─────┬─────┬─────┐
// ┃Num  ┃ / ₁ │ · ₂ │ - ₃ │ ₁ <XF86_Ungrab>
// ┃Lock⇭┃ / ÷ │ * × │ - - │ ₂ <XF86_ClearGrab>
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼─────┤ ₃ <XF86_Prev_VMode>
//                   │ + ₄ │ ₄ <XF86_Next_VMode>
//                   │     │
//                   ┤     │ 1 None
//                   │     │ 2 Level3 ⇮
//                   │ + + │ 3 Shift+Level3 ⇧⇮
//                   ╆━━━━━┪ 4 Ctrl+Alt
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "ossmath_latin9" {

    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_X";

    key <KPDV> { [   KP_Divide,          slash, division,     XF86_Ungrab ] }; // / / ÷     <XF86_Ungrab>
    key <KPMU> { [ KP_Multiply, periodcentered, multiply,  XF86_ClearGrab ] }; // * · ×  <XF86_ClearGrab>
    key <KPSU> { [ KP_Subtract,          minus,    minus, XF86_Prev_VMode ] }; // - - - <XF86_Prev_VMode>

    key <KPAD> { [      KP_Add,           plus,     plus, XF86_Next_VMode ] }; // + + + <XF86_Next_VMode>
};


// Legacy keypad number area
// Copyright © 2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱
// ┃Num  ┃                   ⇱ Home
// ┃Lock⇭┃                   ⇲ End
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼       ⇞ Page up
// │ 7   │ 8   │ 9   │       ⇟ Page down
// │ ⇱   │ ⇧   │ ⇞   │       ⎀ Insert
// ├─────┼─────┼─────┤       ␥ Delete
// │ 4   │ 5   │ 6   │       ⇦⇧⇨⇩ Directions
// │ ⇦   │     │ ⇨   │
// ├─────┼─────┼─────╆
// │ 1   │ 2   │ 3   ┃
// │ ⇲   │ ⇩   │ ⇟   ┃       1 None
// ├─────┴─────┼─────┨       2 Num Lock ⇭
// │ 0         │
// │ ⎀         │
// └───────────┴
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "legacynumber" {

    key.type[Group1]="KEYPAD" ;

    key <KP7>  { [   KP_Home,       KP_7 ] }; //   <home> 7
    key <KP8>  { [     KP_Up,       KP_8 ] }; //     <up> 8
    key <KP9>  { [  KP_Prior,       KP_9 ] }; //  <prior> 9

    key <KP4>  { [   KP_Left,       KP_4 ] }; //   <left> 4
    key <KP5>  { [  KP_Begin,       KP_5 ] }; //  <begin> 5
    key <KP6>  { [  KP_Right,       KP_6 ] }; //  <right> 6

    key <KP1>  { [    KP_End,       KP_1 ] }; //    <end> 1
    key <KP2>  { [   KP_Down,       KP_2 ] }; //   <down> 2
    key <KP3>  { [   KP_Next,       KP_3 ] }; //   <next> 3

    key <KP0>  { [ KP_Insert,       KP_0 ] }; // <insert> 0
};


// Legacy Wang 725-3771-ae and 725-3771-uk keypad number area
// Copyright © 2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
// This is actually a three-level keypad, declared as four-level
// to avoid defining a new type
//
// ┏━━━━━┱
// ┃Num  ┃                   ⇱ Home
// ┃Lock⇭┃                   ⇲ End
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼       ⇞ Page up
// │ 7   │ 8   │ 9   │       ⇟ Page down
// │ ⇱ < │ ⇧ > │ ⇞ ^ │       ⎀ Insert
// ├─────┼─────┼─────┤       ␥ Delete
// │ 4   │ 5   │ 6   │       ⇦⇧⇨⇩ Directions
// │ ⇦ [ │   ] │ ⇨ $ │
// ├─────┼─────┼─────╆
// │ 1   │ 2   │ 3   ┃
// │ ⇲ & │ ⇩ @ │ ⇟ # ┃       1 None
// ├─────┴─────┼─────┨       2 Num Lock ⇭
// │ 0         │             3 Level3 ⇮
// │ ⎀         │
// └───────────┴
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "legacynumber_wang" {

    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD" ;

    key <KP7>  { [   KP_Home,   KP_7,         less ] }; //   <home> 7 <
    key <KP8>  { [     KP_Up,   KP_8,      greater ] }; //     <up> 8 >
    key <KP9>  { [  KP_Prior,   KP_9,  asciicircum ] }; //  <prior> 9 ^

    key <KP4>  { [   KP_Left,   KP_4,  bracketleft ] }; //   <left> 4 [
    key <KP5>  { [  KP_Begin,   KP_5, bracketright ] }; //  <begin> 5 ]
    key <KP6>  { [  KP_Right,   KP_6,       dollar ] }; //  <right> 6 $

    key <KP1>  { [    KP_End,   KP_1,    ampersand ] }; //    <end> 1 &
    key <KP2>  { [   KP_Down,   KP_2,           at ] }; //   <down> 2 @
    key <KP3>  { [   KP_Next,   KP_3,   numbersign ] }; //   <next> 3 #

    key <KP0>  { [ KP_Insert,   KP_0,   apostrophe ] }; // <insert> 0 '
};


// Keypad number area with arrow symbols
// Copyright © 2006 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱
// ┃Num  ┃                   ⇱ Home
// ┃Lock⇭┃                   ⇲ End
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼       ⇞ Page up
// │ 7 ⇖ │ 8 ⇑ │ 9 ⇗ │       ⇟ Page down
// │ ⇱ ↖ │ ⇧ ↑ │ ⇞ ↗ │       ⎀ Insert
// ├─────┼─────┼─────┤       ␥ Delete
// │ 4 ⇐ │ 5 ⇔ │ 6 ⇒ │       ⇦⇧⇨⇩ Directions
// │ ⇦ ← │   ↔ │ ⇨ → │       ⍽ narrow no-break space
// ├─────┼─────┼─────╆
// │ 1 ⇙ │ 2 ⇓ │ 3 ⇘ ┃
// │ ⇲ ↙ │ ⇩ ↓ │ ⇟ ↘ ┃       1 None
// ├─────┴─────┼─────┨       2 Num Lock ⇭
// │ 0       ⇕ │             3 Level3 ⇮
// │ ⎀       ↕ │             4 Shift+Level3 ⇧⇮
// └───────────┴
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "ossnumber" {

    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD" ;

    key <KP7>  { [   KP_Home,   KP_7, 0x1002196, 0x10021D6 ] }; //   <home> 7 ↖ ⇖
    key <KP8>  { [     KP_Up,   KP_8, 0x1002191, 0x10021D1 ] }; //     <up> 8 ↑ ⇑
    key <KP9>  { [  KP_Prior,   KP_9, 0x1002197, 0x10021D7 ] }; //  <prior> 9 ↗ ⇗

    key <KP4>  { [   KP_Left,   KP_4, 0x1002190, 0x10021D0 ] }; //   <left> 4 ← ⇐
    key <KP5>  { [  KP_Begin,   KP_5, 0x1002194, 0x10021D4 ] }; //  <begin> 5 ↔ ⇔
    key <KP6>  { [  KP_Right,   KP_6, 0x1002192, 0x10021D2 ] }; //  <right> 6 → ⇒

    key <KP1>  { [    KP_End,   KP_1, 0x1002199, 0x10021D9 ] }; //    <end> 1 ↙ ⇙
    key <KP2>  { [   KP_Down,   KP_2, 0x1002193, 0x10021D3 ] }; //   <down> 2 ↓ ⇓
    key <KP3>  { [   KP_Next,   KP_3, 0x1002198, 0x10021D8 ] }; //   <next> 3 ↘ ⇘

    key <KP0>  { [ KP_Insert,   KP_0, 0x1002195, 0x10021D5 ] }; // <insert> 0 ↕ ⇕
};


// Wang 725-3771-ae and 725-3771-uk keypad number area with additional arrow symbols
// Copyright © 2007 Nicolas Mailhot <nicolas.mailhot @ laposte.net>
//
// ┏━━━━━┱
// ┃Num  ┃                   ⇱ Home
// ┃Lock⇭┃                   ⇲ End
// ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼       ⇞ Page up
// │ 7 ↖ │ 8 ↑ │ 9 ↗ │       ⇟ Page down
// │ ⇱ < │ ⇧ > │ ⇞ ^ │       ⎀ Insert
// ├─────┼─────┼─────┤       ␥ Delete
// │ 4 ← │ 5 ↔ │ 6 → │       ⇦⇧⇨⇩ Directions
// │ ⇦ [ │   ] │ ⇨ $ │       ⍽ narrow no-break space
// ├─────┼─────┼─────╆
// │ 1 ↙ │ 2 ↓ │ 3 ↘ ┃
// │ ⇲ & │ ⇩ @ │ ⇟ # ┃       1 None
// ├─────┴─────┼─────┨       2 Num Lock ⇭
// │ 0       ↕ │             3 Level3 ⇮
// │ ⎀       ' │             4 Shift+Level3 ⇧⇮
// └───────────┴
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "ossnumber_wang" {

    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD" ;

    key <KP7>  { [   KP_Home,   KP_7,         less, 0x1002196 ] }; //   <home> 7 < ↖
    key <KP8>  { [     KP_Up,   KP_8,      greater, 0x1002191 ] }; //     <up> 8 > ↑
    key <KP9>  { [  KP_Prior,   KP_9,  asciicircum, 0x1002197 ] }; //  <prior> 9 ^ ↗

    key <KP4>  { [   KP_Left,   KP_4,  bracketleft, 0x1002190 ] }; //   <left> 4 [ ←
    key <KP5>  { [  KP_Begin,   KP_5, bracketright, 0x1002194 ] }; //  <begin> 5 ] ↔
    key <KP6>  { [  KP_Right,   KP_6,       dollar, 0x1002192 ] }; //  <right> 6 $ →

    key <KP1>  { [    KP_End,   KP_1,    ampersand, 0x1002199 ] }; //    <end> 1 & ↙
    key <KP2>  { [   KP_Down,   KP_2,           at, 0x1002193 ] }; //   <down> 2 @ ↓
    key <KP3>  { [   KP_Next,   KP_3,   numbersign, 0x1002198 ] }; //   <next> 3 # ↘

    key <KP0>  { [ KP_Insert,   KP_0,   apostrophe, 0x1002195 ] }; // <insert> 0 ' ↕
};

// Standard base "pc" layout only contains cursor keys, and then gets
// augmented with the digits later. If you define your own layout for
// the numpad you can inherit the cursors, but you'll have to define
// the digits yourself. This module can be included in the rules to
// define math operators; these are the variants used in computer
// languages that are based on ASCII. NoSymbol doesn't mean that
// nothing is bound to the key but that no assignment is done here.
// srvr_ctrl(stdkeypad) and keypad(x11) declare the operator keys to
// be of type CTRL+ALT in order to assign server control events to
// them, but it uses the second level which is overwritten if we have
// more than one definition (shift state) for the key. Instead, here
// the commands are put at the fourth level.
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "ops" {
    key <KPDV> { [ NoSymbol,  slash,     NoSymbol,  XF86_Ungrab     ] };
    key <KPMU> { [ NoSymbol,  asterisk,  NoSymbol,  XF86_ClearGrab  ] };
    key <KPSU> { [ NoSymbol,  minus,     NoSymbol,  XF86_Prev_VMode ] };
    key <KPAD> { [ NoSymbol,  plus,      NoSymbol,  XF86_Next_VMode ] };
    key <KPEQ> { [ NoSymbol,  equal      ] };
};

// Hexadecimal Numpad, by Roland Kaufmann <rlndkfmn at gmail dot com>
// License: BSD (also covers variant with ATM digit order)
// Third-level gives the letters used in hexadecimal numbers, or
// columns in small spreadsheets. As a bonus, having 'e' available at
// the center of the keyboard makes it easy to enter floating point
// numbers in scientific notation.
// Equal is added to start formulas (most numpads on PCs don't have
// their own equal key), comma as a list separator (as most
// programming languages wants period as a decimal separator) and
// colon to enter times and ranges. Someone also may want to represent
// multiplication and division in prose using x and colon.
// Two first levels are specified as NoSymbol to not override any
// previous specification. Combine this with another keypad specifier,
// e.g. "legacy".
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "hex" {
    key.type[Group1]="FOUR_LEVEL_MIXED_KEYPAD" ;

    //             None       NumLock    AltGr
    // symbol row
    key <KPDV> { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  parenleft  ] };
    key <KPMU> { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  parenright ] };
    key <KPSU> { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  dollar     ] };

    // upper row
    key <KP7>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  a          ] };
    key <KP8>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  b          ] };
    key <KP9>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  c          ] };

    // home row
    key <KP4>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  d          ] };
    key <KP5>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  e          ] };
    key <KP6>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  f          ] };
    key <KPAD> { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  comma      ] };

    // lower row
    key <KP1>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  equal      ] };
    key <KP2>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  x          ] };
    key <KP3>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  colon      ] };

    // decimal row
    key <KP0>  { [ NoSymbol,  NoSymbol,  backslash  ] };
};

// Main numbers follows the traditions from ATMs and phones with
// numbers increasing downwards to the right. (It is easier to
// change the keyboard layout than to reprogram your local ATM;
// also cell-phones are becoming more common while calculators are
// becoming more rare).
// First level is left unspecified, so it may be combined with another
// layout, e.g. "legacy".
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "atm" {
    // upper row
    key <KP7>  { [ NoSymbol,  KP_1 ] };
    key <KP8>  { [ NoSymbol,  KP_2 ] };
    key <KP9>  { [ NoSymbol,  KP_3 ] };

    // lower row
    key <KP1>  { [ NoSymbol,  KP_7 ] };
    key <KP2>  { [ NoSymbol,  KP_8 ] };
    key <KP3>  { [ NoSymbol,  KP_9 ] };
};


partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "pointerkeys" {
    key <NMLK> { [ Num_Lock, Pointer_EnableKeys ] };
};


// Only numbers, operators and decimal separator,
// as seen on keypad overlay on Japanese keyboard.
// ┌─┬─┬─┬─┐
// │7│8│9│*│
// ├─┼─┼─┼─┤
// │4│5│6│-│
// ├─┼─┼─┼─┤
// │1│2│3│+│
// ├─┼─┼─┼─┤
// │0│ │·│/│
// └─┴─┴─┴─┘
partial keypad_keys
xkb_symbols "numoperdecsep" {
    key  <KO7> {    [  KP_7 ]   };
    key  <KO8> {    [  KP_8 ]   };
    key  <KO9> {    [  KP_9 ]   };
// ClsGrb kills whichever client has a grab in effect
    key <KOMU> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, KP_Multiply, XF86_ClearGrab ]
    };

    key  <KO4> {    [  KP_4 ]   };
    key  <KO5> {    [  KP_5 ]   };
    key  <KO6> {    [  KP_6 ]   };
// -VMode switches to the previous video mode
    key <KOSU> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, KP_Subtract, XF86_Prev_VMode ]
    };

    key  <KO1> {    [  KP_1 ]   };
    key  <KO2> {    [  KP_2 ]   };
    key  <KO3> {    [  KP_3 ]   };
// +VMode switches to the next video mode
    key <KOAD> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Add, KP_Add, KP_Add, KP_Add, XF86_Next_VMode ]
    };

    key  <KO0> {    [  KP_0 ]   };
    key <KODL> {    [ KP_Decimal ]  };
// Ungrab cancels server/keyboard/pointer grabs
    key <KODV> {
        type="CTRL+ALT",
        symbols[Group1]= [ KP_Divide, KP_Divide, KP_Divide, KP_Divide, XF86_Ungrab ]
    };
};
```

Then I ran:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xkb-data
```

After a restart the problem is solved.