# How can I remap the keys/keycodes of a usb foot switch on SystemD?

Tags: udev, systemd

I was using the old udev rules to remap my usb foot switch key(the default is the keycode 36 -b :S) to Alt_L. Previosly I created a udev rule and a xmodmap file. But i'm trying the systemd now, and the old style keymaps are gone.

My usb foot switch is the following(lsusb output):

```
0c45:7403 Microdia Foot Switch
```

In my old udev files, i had the following content:

/etc/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules

```
"ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="0c45", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="7403", RUN+="keymap $name microdia"
```

/lib/udev/keymaps/microdia

```
0x70005 F13
```

~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode 191 = Alt_L Meta_L Alt_L Meta_L
```

So, when I was  pulling the switch the effect is that the key 'ALT_L' was pressed. How can i reproduce the same setup with the systemd/udev hwdb?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap certain keys?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys)

Comment: I dont think so. First I need to remap the keycode of the device (which uses the 'b' by default) and the old udev keymap rules does that, but i cant reproduce the same structure with the systemd and udev hwdb :S

Comment: Does it not show up in xev?

Comment: It shows as the following:

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x1e8, subw 0x0, time 112493, (165,-6), root:(1036,438),
    state 0x10, keycode 56 (keysym 0x62, b), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (62) "b"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: Right, so then use the instructions there with keycode `56`.