# SOLVED Ubuntu has mapped left Ctrl key to my fn key on my hp laptop Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

There seems to be a problem with my left Ctrl key in Ubuntu 14.04. It is switched with my fn key, i.e. Ubuntu thinks I'm pressing the fn key, and when I actually press the fn key it thinks I'm pressing the Ctrl key. This is really frustrating and limiting my productivity! How do I fix it?

- Ok I just found an answer to this yesterday. It turns out it's not Ubuntu that is the problem, something with the BIOS got messed up. So what fixed it is just unplugging the computer and taking the battery out for a couple of seconds : ) such a frustrating problem yet so easy to solve.

Comment: Looks like people are voting to close this without telling you why... This sounds like a bug, not a question that people here will be able to answer for you. You should [report Ubuntu bugs on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug).

Comment: Like michaelms says, it would be a good idea to report this as a bug. I do recommend you read [ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) first though. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I just found an answer to this yesterday. It turns out it's not Ubuntu that is the problem, something with the BIOS got messed up. So what fixed it is just unplugging the computer and taking the battery out for a couple of seconds : ) such a frustrating problem yet so easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to remap the keys. The link below has an extensive answer that will be very useful to achieve it:

[How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Comment: yeah but u cannot remap the fn key as it's off access to the OS. If u try xev and fn u will see nothing happens.