# How to switch the left ctrl key and the left alt key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 14.10

I've been trying to do this for 6 hours but my efforts were of no avail. I  tried make changes to the pc and winalt folders in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` but couldn't figure out the correct changes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Answer (score 3):

You should change something in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/` instead. Find the file of your keyboard layout (mine is `evdev`) and then modify the file. The file contains the name of the keys and numbers that correspond to the key. You should only switch the numbers of the LCTL key and the LALT key. Don't forget to delete all .xkm files in the `/var/lib/xkb/` directory and restart xorg. Proceed with caution, backup the file before you modified it.