# How to remap CapsLock to ctrl+c (copy) and Esc to ctrl+v (paste)?

Tags: keyboard, remapping, capslock

I am running Xfce under Xubuntu 14.04, 32-bit.

My finger are arthritic/stiff, so that I must lift up my hands to type each letter, as they do not move independently enough that I can keep my hands   anchored and type.

And as I do a lot of copy paste operations and use the PC a lot, under Windows I  use AutoHotKey (in which <kbd>^</kbd> is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>) to remap  CapsLock to <kbd>crtrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (copy) and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (paste) and  <kbd>NumLock</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and also the middle mouse key to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> (cut) via a script:

CapsLock::^c

Esc::^v

NumLock::Esc

mbutton::^x

I can run AutoHotKey under Wine but the script  does not work. I also have AutoKey installed, but cannot figure out how to do what i want.

The accepted answer to [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices) does not work in this case because the wev command does not show (from what I see) the key code for key combos: ctrl is the same as ctrl+c, with only the state (state 0x6) being different: state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES.

And it is not clear how to swap the two keys using xmodmap even if I had 2 different key codes.

This is very major issue for me as regards my using Linux. Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)