# Need help changing what my buttons do

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, shortcuts, capslock

I just converted my Chromebook from chromeos to ubuntu and I am an still doing a few remaining tweaks. However I am having trouble, essentially what I want to do is the following:

Change the search button to Caps Lock 
Change the function of my undo, redo, and refresh buttons so whenever I am in my Chrome browser I can go back on a tab or refresh it without having to click the actual browser refresh button.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Answer (score 0):

Use **xbindkeys**..

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Xbindkeys is a very versatile program that lets you remap keys very easily. It uses a config file, my default located in your home directory, to change key bindings into certain commands.

To create a default config file you use the command:

```
xbindkeys --defaults
```

Which prints the default config file. So if you want to create the file containing the default values you would use:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Which prints the default values into a hidden file named .xbindkeysrc located in home (~).

Now to actually change the bindings of keys we first need to know what the name or keysym of those keys is. xbindkeys allows us to use the -k handle to find the name of a key or key combination. Run:

```
xbindkeys -k
```

And press a key or key combination. Your output will look something similar to this (when pressing space):

```
"NoCommand"
m:0x10 + c:65
Mod2 + space
```

"No Command" tells us that currently no command is associated with the Space key.

```
m:0x10 + c:65
Mod2 + space
```

Is the name of the key/key combination.

**the config file..**

Lets open up the config file you made earlier:

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

Here is an excerpt from the default config file:

```
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
# The XK_ is not needed.
#
# List of modifier:
#   Release, Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock),
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll). 
#

# The release modifier is not a standard X modifier, but you can  
# use it if you want to catch release events instead of press events

# By defaults, xbindkeys does not pay attention with the modifiers
# NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock.
# Uncomment the lines above if you want to pay attention to them.

#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock= enable

# Examples of commands:

"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

Every line beginning with # is a comment and won't be read or run by xbindkeys.

So far the only line that isn't commented out is:

```
"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

This excerpt shows the basic syntax of xbindkeys commands:

```
"Command to run (in quotes)"
key to associate with command (no quotes)
```

So as you can see:

```
"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

Runs the command `xbindkeys_show` when you press **Ctrl+Shift+q**.

Comment: for complete configuration you can refer this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard