# Keyboard Remapping help required

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Since someone from the forum suggested to make a separate thread for my each question, here it is.

I want to remap my keyboard.
The letter 'L' is dead and I want to use an alternative, since it's a laptop, I don't have the numpad and I have a next page button which is useless.

So I need to remap the key 'L' to the 'Page next'

[image: layout of the keyboard]

The next page key is just above Left arrow key

Model : IBM T60

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)