# What is the use of modifier keys in Xmodmap?

Tags: keyboard, xorg, xmodmap

I was following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices) question to do some remapping. In the question, there is:

> Additional information: The sequence of these mappings is Key,
>   Shift+Key, mode_switch+Key, mode_switch+Shift+Key, AltGr+Key,
>   AltGr+Shift+Key.

I looked at the modifier keys in Xmodmap in order to understand which modifier key is the `mode_switch` key but did not see any. Then I realized that `mode_switch` is not a modifier key but it is actually a keysym, along with the `Shift` and `AltGr`.

So my question is, is there any combination that makes use of, say Mod5? What is the purpose of these modifier keys?