# Can't seem to switch shift and up keys on laptop

Tags: lenovo, keyboard-layout, remapping

I've been googling around on how to reassign the right shift and up key and I'm having trouble with it and would like some guidance.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

I tried the method mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930829/problems-with-remapping-shift-with-up-keys) post, as this person has the Lenovo Ideapad 510 and I have the Ideapad 710s (both have the same unfortunate keyboard design decision)

The method doesn't work for me as my Up key stopped worked and my right Shift key started acting as both the Up and the Shift key.

I found out that in Ubuntu 16.04, the way to remap the keys would be to go through `/usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols`.

My laptop is using English (US), so I decided to switch around the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift_R</kbd> key in the `/usr/share/x11/xkb/symbols/pc` and then cleared the precompiled keymaps. My <kbd>Up</kbd> key stopped working but my <kbd>Shift</kbd> key remained the same.

I'm at a loss here.

Here is my unformatted pc file.

```
default  partial alphanumeric_keys modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "pc105" {

    key <ESC>  {    [ Escape        ]   };

    // The extra key on many European keyboards:
    key <LSGT> {    [ less, greater, bar, brokenbar ] };

    // The following keys are common to all layouts.
    key <BKSL> {    [ backslash,    bar ]   };
    key <SPCE> {    [    space      ]   };

    include "srvr_ctrl(fkey2vt)"
    include "pc(editing)"
    include "keypad(x11)"

    key <BKSP> {    [ BackSpace, BackSpace  ]   };

    key  <TAB> {    [ Tab,  ISO_Left_Tab    ]   };
    key <RTRN> {    [ Return        ]   };

    key <CAPS> {    [ Caps_Lock     ]   };
    key <NMLK> {    [ Num_Lock      ]   };

    key <LFSH> {    [ Shift_L       ]   };
    key <LCTL> {    [ Control_L     ]   };
    key <LWIN> {    [ Super_L       ]   };

    key <RTSH> {    [ Shift_R       ]   };
    key <RCTL> {    [ Control_R     ]   };
    key <RWIN> {    [ Super_R       ]   };
    key <MENU> {    [ Menu          ]   };

    // Beginning of modifier mappings.
    modifier_map Shift  { Shift_L, Shift_R };
    modifier_map Lock   { Caps_Lock };
    modifier_map Control{ Control_L, Control_R };
    modifier_map Mod2   { Num_Lock };
    modifier_map Mod4   { Super_L, Super_R };

    // Fake keys for virtual<->real modifiers mapping:
    key <LVL3> {    [ ISO_Level3_Shift  ]   };
    key <MDSW> {    [ Mode_switch       ]   };
    modifier_map Mod5   { <LVL3>, <MDSW> };

    key <ALT>  {    [ NoSymbol, Alt_L   ]   };
    include "altwin(meta_alt)"

    key <META> {    [ NoSymbol, Meta_L  ]   };
    modifier_map Mod1   { <META> };

    key <SUPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Super_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <SUPR> };

    key <HYPR> {    [ NoSymbol, Hyper_L ]   };
    modifier_map Mod4   { <HYPR> };
    // End of modifier mappings.

    key <OUTP> { [ XF86Display ] };
    key <KITG> { [ XF86KbdLightOnOff ] };
    key <KIDN> { [ XF86KbdBrightnessDown ] };
    key <KIUP> { [ XF86KbdBrightnessUp ] };
};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "editing" {
    key <PRSC> {
    type= "PC_ALT_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Print, Sys_Req ]
    };
    key <SCLK> {    [  Scroll_Lock      ]   };
    key <PAUS> {
    type= "PC_CONTROL_LEVEL2",
    symbols[Group1]= [ Pause, Break ]
    };
    key  <INS> {    [  Insert       ]   };
    key <HOME> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Prior        ]   };
    key <DELE> {    [  Delete       ]   };
    key  <END> {    [  End          ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Next         ]   };

    key <UP>   {    [  Up           ]   };
    key <LEFT> {    [  Left         ]   };
    key <DOWN> {    [  Down         ]   };
    key <RGHT> {    [  Right        ]   };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue thanks to the answer in [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327389/how-can-i-remap-special-keys-in-xkb?rq=1)

Thanks to @Sparhawk I went to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` and simply switched the keycodes for the `UP` (keycode 111) and `RTSH` (keycode 62) for my keyboard.

I cleared the xkb cache and rebooted and it's done. Hopefully it will stick.