# How can I swap my backspace and backslash?

Tags: keyboard, xbindkeys

I want it like this:

BackSpace -> backslash

Shift + BackSpace -> bar

backslash -> BackSpace

I tried to use xbindkeys and xdotool, but I couldn't get it to work. This is what I had in my .xbindkeysrc file:

```
"xdotool key bar"
  shift + BackSpace
"xdotool key backslash"
  BackSpace
"xdotool key BackSpace"
  backslash
```

However, all this would do is make my keys stop working.

Comment: Check this, it's a workaround but may be usefull to you:
https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/49

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not possible with `xdotool` because your are linking two keys together.. system will struggle when you say `backslash` it reroute to `BackSpace` & when you say `BackSpace` again it reroutes to `backslash` and this loop keep on running

[`backslash`-->`BackSpace`-->`backslash`-->`BackSpace`-->`backslash`-->`so on`-->]

[`BackSpace`-->`backslash`-->`BackSpace`-->`backslash`-->`BackSpace`-->`so on`-->]

your all other keys works if you remove this kind of links..

for example: both of below will work.

```
"xdotool key space"
  Shift + BackSpace + Release
"xdotool key backslash"
  BackSpace + Release
```

or

```
"xdotool key space"
  Shift + BackSpace + Release
"xdotool key BackSpace"
  backslash + Release
```

the best way is to map the keys with this answer..https://askubuntu.com/a/24930/739431

i have tried it on my keybord and easily swapped backslash & BackSpace keys.

Example:

below are the values for the required keys by running `xev` command and pressing required keys.

`state 0x10. keycode 51 (keysym 0X5c, backslash), same_screen YES,`

`stat 0X10, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,`

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = BackSpace"
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = backslash"
```

Comment: `xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = backslash"` made it so that I couldn't type the bar key, but I fixed this with `xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = backslash bar"`

Comment: @James Wang, i have given example in the answer.. your exact key naming can be obtained by `xev` command. any way you could achieve what you need. i am glad about it. Thank You.