# How can I map Ctrl+Backspace to Delete?

Tags: shortcut-keys, settings

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10. What action do I use to map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete one character?

I tried `del`, `delete`, `<del>`, `<delete>`...

Any help is welcome.

Comment: xbindkeys have you tried but you need to simulate with xdotool like xdotool key Delete. And its bit slow. Not worthy but try once.

Comment: This question gives you clue what i mean in above comment. https://askubuntu.com/q/1100493/739431

Answer (score 4):

A simple and reliable way to do that is using the [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) application. Just follow these steps:

1. Install `autokey` and the GUI package for the respective desktop environment you use (`autokey-gtk` for GTK-based environments (like GNOME, Xfce, Mate) or `autokey-qt` for QT-based environments (like KDE, LXQt)):

   ```
   sudo apt install autokey-common autokey-gtk
   ```

   or:

   ```
   sudo apt install autokey-common autokey-qt
   ```
2. Open AutoKey and go to *File* → *New* → *Phrase*.
3. In the widow that pops up enter a name for the phrase and click <kbd>OK</kbd>. I'm using *Map Ctrl+Back* for the phrase's name.
4. Select the *Map Ctrl+Back* phrase on the left sidepane (should be under *My Phrases*) and in the main text box enter:

   ```
   <delete>
   ```
5. On the bottom panel click <kbd>Set</kbd> on the *Hotkey* option → click <kbd>Press to Set</kbd> and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
6. Save your phrase by clicking *Save* on the menu bar of the AutoKey window.

That's it! You should now be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to send <kbd>Delete</kbd> keystrokes.

---

**Note:** It is recommended to have AutoKey autostart when you log in to your  desktop, so that you don't have to manually start it every time. To do that go to *Edit* → *Preferences* and check *Automatically start AutoKey at login*.

Comment: A couple of additions. If you select the autostart option and your desktop has already started it as part of restoring the last session, you get an annoying error message and you 
 will need to disable one or the other options, Also, if you need this mapping for some applications, but not others, you can set an appropriate window filter for your script or phrase.