# Turn Caps Lock key into delete key

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, 22.04, remapping

Using Kubuntu on a Macbook there is no delete key. Delete can be done with Backspace+Fn, but there is only one Fn on the farthest corner from Backspace, so that a delete action requires both hands.

I don't use CapsLock for uppercase, I use Shift for that, so CapsLock could be used for delete. I can make it act as a Backspace with the keyboard advanced settings, but this new Backspace **doesn't work with Fn** in order to delete.

How could I make CapsLock work as a key for "Backspace+Fn=delete" or simply turn it into a Delete key?

Comment: Editing the xkb layout files certainly could cut it (assign `Delete` to `<CAPS`). On a PC keyboard, that probably has to be changed in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` (`    key <CAPS> { [ Delete  ] };`, but I have no idea where to change that for an apple keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### X11 solution:

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/1680037/1039759) and [here](https://gist.github.com/rickyzhang82/8581a762c9f9fc6ddb8390872552c250) I have found that the keycode for Capslock is 66. From [here](https://ictsolved.github.io/remap-key-in-linux/) I've got the command to remap Caps Lock as Delete:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Delete"
```

After testing that it worked I have made it run at startup by creating the file `~/.config/autostart/capslock-delete.desktop` (based on last link) with the lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=sh -c 'xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Delete"'
Name=capslock is delete
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

It may happen that the Capslock key continues to trigger lock-uppercase beside doing delete. It needs to be disabled as said [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-deactivate-caps-lock/), or in KDE, under keyboard settings - Advanced - Capslock behavior - Disable...

### Update:

In case the solution of the said above desktop file or command to run at startup is not working, following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1082273/925128) answer, this seems to work in Kubuntu 22.04:

- create a file `~/.Xmodmap` containing the `keycode` setting: `keycode 66 = Delete`
- create a script like for example `~/bin/capslock.delete.sh`:

  ```
   #!/bin/bash           
  sleep 1;               
  echo "running xmodmap" 
  xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
  ```
- make the `.sh` file executable
- add the same script file to be executed at startup

---

In case one still wants a key or key combination to *lock* the upper keys (the CapsLock key default behavior), the following command - [involving `xdotool`](https://www.securitronlinux.com/bejiitaswrath/how-to-toggle-the-caps-lock-key-with-the-command-line-in-linux-mint/) - which can be associated with shortcut like Super+Delete or Alt+Delete (where the key pressed for Delete is of course the real/former CapsLock) - will do:

```
xdotool key Caps_Lock
```

Install *xdotool*:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

I have associated Alt+CapsLock with the command `sh -c 'xdotool key Caps_Lock'`.

(One would expect that `xdotool` might be used in the first place to get the delete action with a command like: `xdotool key Delete`, but that doesn't seem to work very well, as said [here](https://groups.google.com/g/xdotool-users/c/j-omMaTMku4?pli=1); I have been able to use it - sort of - with Ctrl+D, but that only deletes text to the right without deleting files.)

A good alternative to get the delete action (as well as others that I haven't tested) is to use AutoKey, described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392517/925128), about the  delete action:

[image]

---

### Solution for Wayland:

I haven't tested because I don't use Wayland, but I have found [here](https://github.com/k0kubun/xremap) that `xremap` and `modmap` should work as alternatives to `xmodmap`. Also, see the other answer on `keyd`.

Answer (score 1):

For both X11 and Wayland, you can use the remapper deamon [keyd](https://github.com/rvaiya/keyd) for this purpose. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1364828/13884) for installation, usage and tips.

After installation, use this config:

```
[ids]

*

[main]

capslock = delete
```

Comment: This is great as it works in Wayland (as said at link).