# Specific Key Mappings

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am trying to map specific keys to character outputs, such as "Ctrl + O = |". I understand that different language layouts provide different mappings but I want to have more control over them, on any layout. Does anyone know any software or shell scripts I can write to enable this feature?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have searched but not found an answer about this specifically.

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Lara, may I refer you to this page : https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices.  It has the answers to most all you ask.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]