# How to use Caps Lock as ctrl automatically?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, cron, capslock, gnome-tweaks

I used to be able to use my caps lock key as a ctrl using Gnome Tweaks but, despite it being set in Tweaks it is not working anymore. For the past 2 months I've had to periodically open up a non-tmux tab in my console and type `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"`. I've tried setting that in my crontab but it doesn't work there for some reason so I have to do it manually periodically.

However, just today it seems like I have to type this like every 10-15 minutes and is unsustainable. How do I set it permanently? Thanks!

Comment: Please go through with link and try if it can help you

https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices

Comment: why did gnome tweaks stop working

Comment: The Ubuntu version you are using might be important in this.

Comment: With tweaks the Ubuntu version is important and not stated.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS