# How can I move the Esc key to Alt and AltGr

Tags: keyboard

I'm using gVim and want to move Esc to Alt and AltGr. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remap certain keys or devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24916/how-do-i-remap-certain-keys-or-devices)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem in Vim Stack Exchange. Instead of using Esc I can use C - [.
That isn't exactly what I were asking for but it's a good solution to the problem and I will use it. The answer come from Amir Eldor Aug 1,2018 and it was an answer to the "Remap Esc Key in Vim" question made Aug 6, 2018.