# Extra Mouse button assigned to Super-W short cut

Tags: 10.04, mouse

I have assigned my middle click mouse button to the shortcut Super-W in Ubuntu 10.04, now I need to change this binding, but I can not remember how I did it...

I've not used Btnx,xbindkeys, this are not installed...

Answer (score 0):

That sounds more like something set via CCSM/CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Comment: I can't find anything in CCSM... I remember I'v used xev to find out the number of my middle button...

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

[Map caps-lock key to middle mouse click](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17294/map-caps-lock-key-to-middle-mouse-click)

There's an app named xdotool in the question. Maybe you used that.

If not, then maybe you have used gconf-editor, as described here:

http://ubuntuguide.net/assign-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu